# Array slices in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

How do you do it? Given a byte array:

```
byte[] foo = new byte[4096];
```

How would I get the first x bytes of the array as a separate array? (Specifically, I need it as an `IEnumerable<byte>`)

This is for working with `Socket`s. I figure the easiest way would be array slicing, similar to Perls syntax:

```
@bar = @foo[0..40];
```

Which would return the first 41 elements into the `@bar` array. Is there something in C# that I'm just missing, or is there some other thing I should be doing?

LINQ is an option for me (.NET 3.5), if that helps any.

Comment: Array slicing is a proposal for c#  7.2  https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/185

Comment: C# 8.0 will see the introduction of native array slicing. [See answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55498674/8628766)

Comment: You might be interested in ArraySlice<T> which implements slicing of arrays with step as a view over the original data: https://github.com/henon/SliceAndDice

Answer (score 242, accepted):

Arrays are enumerable, so your `foo` already is an `IEnumerable<byte>` itself.
Simply use LINQ sequence methods like [`Take()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx) to get what you want out of it (don't forget to include the `Linq` namespace with  `using System.Linq;`):

```
byte[] foo = new byte[4096];

var bar = foo.Take(41);
```

If you really need an array from any `IEnumerable<byte>` value, you could use the `ToArray()` method for that. That does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: If we are going to copy to another array just use the Array.Copy static method.  However I think the other answers have interpreted the intent correctly, another array is not required just an IEnumberable<byte> that over the first 41 bytes.

Comment: Note that only single dimensional and jagged arrays are enumerable, multi dimensional arrays are not.

Comment: Note using Array.Copy performs a lot faster than using LINQ's Take or Skip methods.

Comment: @Abel That is actually very incorrect. Multi dimensional arrays *are* enumerable but they enumerate like this: `[2,3] => [1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [2,1], [2,2], [2,3]`. Jagged arrays are also enumerable but instead of returning a value when enumerated, they return their inner array. Like this: `type[][] jaggedArray; foreach (type[] innerArray in jaggedArray) { }`

Comment: @Aidiakapi "very incorect"? ;). But you're partially right, I should have writte "multidim arrays do not implement `IEnumerable<T>`", then my statement would've been clearer. See also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721882/multidimensional-arrays-do-not-implement-ienumerablet-or-do-they

Answer (score 251):

You could use [`ArraySegment<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx). It's very light-weight as it doesn't copy the array:

```
string[] a = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };
var segment = new ArraySegment<string>( a, 1, 2 );
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not IEnumerable.

Comment: True, but it would be easy to write an iterator wrapper around it that implements IEnumerable.

Comment: Does anyone know WHY it's not IEnumerable?  I don't.  It seems like it should be.

Comment: Yes, ideally Array and ArraySegment would inherit from a common base (IArray?), and both implement ICollection, IEnumerable and IList. As it is, ArraySegment isn't very generally useful.

Comment: @Fantius, because `ArraySegment<T>` is a wrapper around a given array, without creating a copy out of it. If it's an `IEnumerable<T>`, then you don't actually know what's behind it, so you'd end up with another copy of the given `IEnumerable<T>` as an array. You'll have to hold such array, so you could provide random access to any index, with O(1) in time.

Comment: @RonKlein, I know it is a wrapper and it does not make a copy.  The rest of your explanation lost me.

Comment: ArraySegment is IList and IEnumerable starting from .Net 4.5. Too bad for older version users..

Comment: @Yuxiu Li, IEnumerable is not new from .NET 4.5 it's old as IList from .NET 2.0. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Zyo I meant ArraySegment<T> implements IEnumerable<T> starting from .Net 4.5, not IEnumerable<T> itself is new.

Comment: The resulting `ArraySegment` will iterate well with a `foreach` statement, but not so much in a usual `for` statement. The quick fix for that is to cast it to an `IList<T>`. Otherwise, it will require the use of  `int i = theSegment.Offset` and `i < (theSegment.Offset + theSegment.Count)` parameters, as well as a call to `theSegment.Array[i]` in the body to work as expected.

Comment: Note: ArraySegement throws an exception if count is larger than the actual array, while Take() does not.

Comment: `doesn't copy the array` also means it's not thread-safe, right?

Comment: Too bad you can't create do `new ArraySegment<T>(myArraySegment, myOffset, MyCount)`. Would be useful for recursing over arrays, for example binary search over a sorted array.

Comment: @Jonathan isn't this basically simply `new ArraySegment<YourType>(myArraySegment.Array, myOffset, MyCount)` ? ;)

Answer (score 169):

You could use the arrays `CopyTo()` method.

Or with LINQ you can use `Skip()` and [`Take()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx)...

```
byte[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
var subset = arr.Skip(2).Take(2);
```

Comment: +1 for a good idea, but I need to use the returned array as input for another function, which makes CopyTo require a temporary variable. I'll wait for other answers yet.

Comment: I'm not familiar with LINQ yet, perhaps this is further evidence that I really should be.

Comment: this approach is at least 50x slower than Array.Copy. This isn't an issue in many situations but when doing array slicing in a cycle, the performance drop is very obvious.

Comment: I'm making a single call, so performance is not an issue for me.  This is great for readability...thanks.

Comment: Thanks for `Skip()`. Just `Take()` won't get you an arbitrary slice. Besides, I was looking for a LINQ solution anyway (slice IEnumerable, but I knew results about array would be easier to find).

Answer (score 84):

**Starting from C# 8.0/.Net Core 3.0**

Array slicing will be supported, along with the new types `Index` and `Range` being added.

[Range Struct docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.range?view=netcore-3.0)
[Index Struct docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.index?view=netcore-3.0)

```cs
Index i1 = 3;  // number 3 from beginning
Index i2 = ^4; // number 4 from end
int[] a = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
Console.WriteLine($"{a[i1]}, {a[i2]}"); // "3, 6"

var slice = a[i1..i2]; // { 3, 4, 5 }
```

Above code sample taken from the C# 8.0 [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/building-c-8-0/).

note that the `^` prefix indicates counting from the *end* of the array. As shown in the [docs example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges)

```cs
var words = new string[]
{
                // index from start    index from end
    "The",      // 0                   ^9
    "quick",    // 1                   ^8
    "brown",    // 2                   ^7
    "fox",      // 3                   ^6
    "jumped",   // 4                   ^5
    "over",     // 5                   ^4
    "the",      // 6                   ^3
    "lazy",     // 7                   ^2
    "dog"       // 8                   ^1
};              // 9 (or words.Length) ^0
```

`Range` and `Index` also work outside of slicing arrays, for example with loops

```
Range range = 1..4; 
foreach (var name in names[range])
```

Will loop through the entries 1 through 4

---

<sub><s>note that at the time of writing this answer, C# 8.0 is not yet officially released</s></sub>
<sub>C# 8.x and .Net Core 3.x are now available in Visual Studio 2019 and onwards</sub>

Comment: any idea whether or not this creates a copy of the array?

Comment: seems like it's a copy:
https://www.codejourney.net/2019/02/csharp-8-slicing-indexes-ranges/

Comment: Ridiculously, none of the documentation tells what type I get after slicing. Is it another array? Or is it an ArraySegment? Or what?...

Comment: @C-F, Turns out it is a new array.

Comment: I really wish the second number was inclusive... `1..4` means 1, 2, and 3, NOT 4.

Answer (score 59):

```
static byte[] SliceMe(byte[] source, int length)
{
    byte[] destfoo = new byte[length];
    Array.Copy(source, 0, destfoo, 0, length);
    return destfoo;
}
```

//

```
var myslice = SliceMe(sourcearray,41);
```

Comment: I think Buffer.BlockCopy() is more efficient and achieves the same results.

Comment: @MattDavis No, it is **slightly efficient** in some circumstances. Look at this post about Array and Buffer copy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389821/array-copy-vs-buffer-blockcopy.

Answer (score 28):

In [C# 7.2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/15/welcome-to-c-7-2-and-span/), you can use [`Span<T>`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/master/docs/specs/span.md). The benefit of the new [`System.Memory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814808.aspx) system is that it doesn't need copying around data.

The method you need is `Slice`:

```
Span<byte> slice = foo.Slice(0, 40);
```

A lot of methods now support `Span` and `IReadOnlySpan`, so it will be very straightforward to use this new type.

Note that at the time of writing the `Span<T>` type is not defined in the the most recent version of .NET yet (4.7.1) so to use it you need to install the [System.Memory package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/) from NuGet.

Answer (score 26):

C# 8 now (since 2019) supports [Ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges) which allows you to achieve Slice much easier (similar to JS syntax):

```
var array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var slice1 = array[2..^3];    // array[new Range(2, new Index(3, fromEnd: true))]
var slice2 = array[..^3];     // array[Range.EndAt(new Index(3, fromEnd: true))]
var slice3 = array[2..];      // array[Range.StartAt(2)]
var slice4 = array[..];       // array[Range.All]
```

You can use ranges instead of the well known LINQ functions: **Skip()**, **Take()**, **Count()**.

Comment: var var var. No clue what type is in return

Comment: @IC_ I is a code example from Microsoft documentation (link in the answer). Also after the =  it is clearly seen `int[]` So the anserver to your question it is INT but when you type in the code IDE shows the types for `var` as well (hover over, etc.)

Comment: I mean that it is not obvious what types actually are after syntax `var a = arr[2..^3]`. It can't be either `int[]` or `ArraySegment<int>`, the latter is not useful at all when you API expects `int[]` to take

Comment: @IC_ again this is a code samle from [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges#systemrange) Link added to the original answer as well.. So they explain it like that, you can complain to Microsoft.
And still in an IDE type is shown, so very easy to find out. But to help you it will be `int[]`

Comment: So what does this actually produce? For example, what is the length of `array[2:3]`? In most languages I'm familiar with, I would expect 2. In Python, I would expect 1.

Comment: @Harry you can reed the MS docs on ranges https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges Also I don't think C# version supports [2:3] it uses [..]. In you case you want to select single element with ranges which is just a simple indexing [2] or [3] or you can use LINQ methods like ElementAt(x)....

Comment: @Major That doc is one of the first things I found with a web search, but it's painfully verbose and after an hour of reading I was none the wiser. I just want to know if `array[2..3]` has length 1 or 2.

Comment: What happens if you, using the code above, say `var slice5 = array[5..];`? Do you get an empty int[] or do you get a range exception?

Comment: @jmucchiello Please read MS documentation on Ranges. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges

Answer (score 17):

Another possibility I haven't seen mentioned here: Buffer.BlockCopy() is slightly faster than Array.Copy(), and it has the added benefit of being able to convert on-the-fly from an array of primitives (say, short[]) to an array of bytes, which can be handy when you've got numeric arrays that you need to transmit over Sockets.

Comment: `Buffer.BlockCopy` produced different results than `Array.Copy()` even though they accept the same parameters - there were a lot of empty elements. Why?

Comment: @jocull - They don't actually quite take the same parameters. Array.Copy() takes its length and position parameters in elements. Buffer.BlockCopy() takes its length and position parameters in bytes. In other words, if you wanted to copy a 10-element array of integers, you would use `Array.Copy(array1, 0, array2, 0, 10)`, but `Buffer.BlockCopy(array1, 0, array2, 0, 10 * sizeof(int))`.

Answer (score 15):

If you want `IEnumerable<byte>`, then just

```
IEnumerable<byte> data = foo.Take(x);
```

Answer (score 13):

Here's a simple extension method that returns a slice as a new array:

```
public static T[] Slice<T>(this T[] arr, uint indexFrom, uint indexTo) {
    if (indexFrom > indexTo) {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("indexFrom is bigger than indexTo!");
    }

    uint length = indexTo - indexFrom;
    T[] result = new T[length];
    Array.Copy(arr, indexFrom, result, 0, length);

    return result;
}
```

Then you can use it as:

```
byte[] slice = foo.Slice(0, 40);
```

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to add [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) or other extensions just do:

```
float[] subArray = new List<float>(myArray).GetRange(0, 8).ToArray();
```

Comment: `Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'List<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`  The Microsoft documentation is hopeless with hundreds of "List" entries indexed.  What is the right one here?

Comment: `System.Collections.Generic.List`

Answer (score 7):

You could use a wrapper around the original array (which is IList), like in this (untested) piece of code.

```cs
public class SubList<T> : IList<T>
{
    #region Fields

    private readonly int startIndex;
    private readonly int endIndex;
    private readonly int count;
    private readonly IList<T> source;

    #endregion

    public SubList(IList<T> source, int startIndex, int count)
    {
        this.source = source;
        this.startIndex = startIndex;
        this.count = count;
        this.endIndex = this.startIndex + this.count - 1;
    }

    #region IList<T> Members

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            for (int i = this.startIndex; i <= this.endIndex; i++)
            {
                if (item.Equals(this.source[i]))
                    return i;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = this.startIndex; i <= this.endIndex; i++)
            {
                if (this.source[i] == null)
                    return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index >= 0 && index < this.count)
                return this.source[index + this.startIndex];
            else
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("index");
        }
        set
        {
            if (index >= 0 && index < this.count)
                this.source[index + this.startIndex] = value;
            else
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("index");
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICollection<T> Members

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return this.IndexOf(item) >= 0;
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<this.count; i++)
        {
            array[arrayIndex + i] = this.source[i + this.startIndex];
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return this.count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<T> Members

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = this.startIndex; i < this.endIndex; i++)
        {
            yield return this.source[i];
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using EqualityComparer.Default for IndexOf - that way you don't need any special casing.

Comment: I'd expect it to be absolutely fine. I'd certainly go with the simpler code first.

Comment: Something like this is in my opinion the best way to go. But obviously it's more work (the first time) than a simple `Array.Copy`, even though this can have many advantages, such as the SubList literally being a region within the parent List, instead of a copy of the entries in the List.

Answer (score 7):

```
byte[] foo = new byte[4096]; 

byte[] bar = foo.Take(40).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 7):

For byte arrays [System.Buffer.BlockCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) will give you the very best performance.

Comment: Which only really matters if you're doing this in a loop thousands or millions of times. In a sockets application, you're probably taking some input and breaking it into parts. If you're only doing it once, the very best performance is whatever the next programmer will most easily understand.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Take extension method

```
var array = new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
var firstTwoItems = array.Take(2);
```

Answer (score 3):

This may be a solution that:

```
var result = foo.Slice(40, int.MaxValue);
```

Then the **result** is an **IEnumerable< IEnumerable< byte>>** with a first **IEnumerable< byte>** contains the first 40 bytes of **foo**, and a second **IEnumerable< byte>** holds the rest.

I wrote a wrapper class, the whole iteration is lazy, hope it could help:

```
public static class CollectionSlicer
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Slice<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, params int[] steps)
    {
        if (!steps.Any(step => step != 0))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't slice a collection with step length 0.");
        }
        return new Slicer<T>(source.GetEnumerator(), steps).Slice();
    }
}

public sealed class Slicer<T>
{
    public Slicer(IEnumerator<T> iterator, int[] steps)
    {
        _iterator = iterator;
        _steps = steps;
        _index = 0;
        _currentStep = 0;
        _isHasNext = true;
    }

    public int Index
    {
        get { return _index; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Slice()
    {
        var length = _steps.Length;
        var index = 1;
        var step = 0;

        for (var i = 0; _isHasNext; ++i)
        {
            if (i < length)
            {
                step = _steps[i];
                _currentStep = step - 1;
            }

            while (_index < index && _isHasNext)
            {
                _isHasNext = MoveNext();
            }

            if (_isHasNext)
            {
                yield return SliceInternal();
                index += step;
            }
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<T> SliceInternal()
    {
        if (_currentStep == -1) yield break;
        yield return _iterator.Current;

        for (var count = 0; count < _currentStep && _isHasNext; ++count)
        {
            _isHasNext = MoveNext();

            if (_isHasNext)
            {
                yield return _iterator.Current;
            }
        }
    }

    private bool MoveNext()
    {
        ++_index;
        return _iterator.MoveNext();
    }

    private readonly IEnumerator<T> _iterator;
    private readonly int[] _steps;
    private volatile bool _isHasNext;
    private volatile int _currentStep;
    private volatile int _index;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not think C# supports the Range semantics. You could write an extension method though, like:

```
public static IEnumerator<Byte> Range(this byte[] array, int start, int end);
```

But like others have said if you do not need to set a start index then `Take` is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension function that uses a generic and behaves like the PHP function [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php). Negative offset and length are allowed.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T[] Slice<T>(this T[] arr, int offset, int length)
    {
        int start, end;
        
        // Determine start index, handling negative offset.
        if (offset < 0)
            start = arr.Length + offset;
        else
            start = offset;
        
        // Clamp start index to the bounds of the input array.
        if (start < 0)
            start = 0;
        else if (start > arr.Length)
            start = arr.Length;

        // Determine end index, handling negative length.
        if (length < 0)
            end = arr.Length + length;
        else
            end = start + length;

        // Clamp end index to the bounds of the input array.
        if (end < 0)
            end = 0;
        if (end > arr.Length)
            end = arr.Length;

        // Get the array slice.
        int len = end - start;
        T[] result = new T[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            result[i] = arr[start + i];
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty good, though a few things from the .NET world. If `start` isn't between 0 and `arr.Length`, it should probably throw an out of bounds exception. Also, `end >= start >= 0`, so you don't need to check `end < 0`, it isn't possible that it will happen. You could probably do it even more succinctly by checking that `length >= 0` and then `len = Math.min(length, arr.Length - start)` instead of the fuddling with `end`.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace data_seniens
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //new list
            float [] x=new float[]{11.25f,18.0f,20.0f,10.75f,9.50f, 11.25f, 18.0f, 20.0f, 10.75f, 9.50f };

            //variable
            float eat_sleep_area=x[1]+x[3];
            //print
            foreach (var VARIABLE in x)
            {
                if (VARIABLE < x[7])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(VARIABLE);
                }
            }



            //keep app run
        Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Often when reading from streams you want to handle reading less that requested.

[Array.Resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize) is your friend in this situation.