# How to copy part of an array to another array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

How can I copy a part of an array to another array?

Consider I'm having

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Now if I give the start index and end index of the array `a` it should get copied to another array.

Like if I give start index as 1 and end index as 3, the elements 2, 3, 4 should get copied in the new array.

Answer (score 306, accepted):

```
int[] b = new int[3];
Array.Copy(a, 1, b, 0, 3);
```

- a = source array
- 1 = start index in source array
- b = destination array
- 0 = start index in destination array
- 3 = elements to copy

Comment: With named parameters that are available now, you would not need to document any of the 5 parameters.

Comment: @Hamish well, maybe. Personally I wouldn't add explicit names unless it made the code significantly clearer, and I'm not sure (in this case) that the parameter names *by themselves* would achieve that.

Answer (score 18):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406485/array-slices-in-c). LINQ Take() and Skip() are the most popular answers, as well as Array.CopyTo().

A purportedly faster [extension method is described here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-slice).

Comment: Another question on SO with a suitable answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3539065/411428

Comment: Note that LINQ is not ideal when dealing with performance-critical situations

Comment: Array.CopyTo copies all elements and the original question is "How to copy A PART of an array?". Also: when already working with an array, Skip() Take() isn't the best option from a performance perspective.

Answer (score 6):

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};

int [] b= new int[a.length]; //New Array and the size of a which is 4

Array.Copy(a,b,a.length);
```

Where Array is class having method Copy, which copies the element of a array to b array.

While copying from one array to another array, you have to provide same data type to another array of which you are copying.

Answer (score 3):

In C# 8+ you can use ranges.

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int b[] = a[1..4]; // b = [2,3,4];
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges

Answer (score 1):

Note: I found this question looking for one of the steps in the answer to how to ***resize*** an existing array.

So I thought I would add that information here, in case anyone else was searching for how to do a ranged copy as a partial answer to the question of resizing an array.

For anyone else finding this question looking for the same thing I was, it is very simple:

```
Array.Resize<T>(ref arrayVariable, newSize);
```

where *T* is the type, i.e. where arrayVariable is declared:

```
T[] arrayVariable;
```

That method handles null checks, as well as newSize==oldSize having no effect, and of course silently handles the case where one of the arrays is longer than the other.

See [the MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to implement your own **Array.Copy** method.

Static method which is of generic type.

```
 static void MyCopy<T>(T[] sourceArray, long sourceIndex, T[] destinationArray, long destinationIndex, long copyNoOfElements)
 {
  long totaltraversal = sourceIndex + copyNoOfElements;
  long sourceArrayLength = sourceArray.Length;

  //to check all array's length and its indices properties before copying
  CheckBoundaries(sourceArray, sourceIndex, destinationArray, copyNoOfElements, sourceArrayLength);
   for (long i = sourceIndex; i < totaltraversal; i++)
     {
      destinationArray[destinationIndex++] = sourceArray[i]; 
     } 
  }
```

Boundary method implementation.

```
private static void CheckBoundaries<T>(T[] sourceArray, long sourceIndex, T[] destinationArray, long copyNoOfElements, long sourceArrayLength)
        {
            if (sourceIndex >= sourceArray.Length)
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            }
            if (copyNoOfElements > sourceArrayLength)
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            }
            if (destinationArray.Length < copyNoOfElements)
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }
```