# copy part of an array into another array

Tags: c#, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to copy part of an array to another array in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733243/how-to-copy-part-of-an-array-to-another-array-in-c)

if i have:

```
string[] myArray =  . . . .
```

which is an array with a length of 10. how can i create a new string array that is the 2nd to 10th elements of the first array without looping?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [System.Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx):

```
string[] myArray = ....
string[] copy = new string[10];
Array.Copy(myArray, 2, copy, 0, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx)

(But note, it will be looping under the covers, just optimally so).

[Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx).

Comment: lol...Just got to it 51s before you did....I like the function but, prefer loops as I can address them how I need.