# c# - how to copy a section of "byte[]" to another array?

Tags: c#, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to copy part of an array to another array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733243/how-to-copy-part-of-an-array-to-another-array-in-c)

c# - how to copy a section of "byte[]" variable to another array?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

how about something like:

```
var byteArray = new byte[] { 1, 0, 1 };
var startIndex = 1;
var length = 2;

byteArray.Skip(startIndex).Take(length).ToArray();
```