# Copy few elements of array to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have two arrays say **arrOne** and **arrTwo**.
now **arrOne** is having **27** elements and **arrTwo** is **vacant**.
On click of a button i want to copy **first 10 elements** of **arrOne** to **arrTwo**, then on second click, i want to add **another 10 elements** and the rest 7 on another click. example with code would be really helpful,,.. thnx   O_o

Comment: Did you try writing something in an attempt to implement this? If so, what happens when you run it?

Comment: Questions of the form, "Here is a specification, please give me the code" aren't very useful. "I have a problem with my code that does X" is a more answerable question.

Comment: ok.. should i use this?? [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733243/how-to-copy-part-of-an-array-to-another-array-in-c)

Comment: Do you have c style arrays or do you have NSArray objects?

Comment: So a way for you to break this problem down is to a) work out how to hook up a button to some code you write, b) how to manipulate NSMutableArray objects (and use NSArrays) -- read the Apple API docs, c) tie it all together in some code you write, d) ask here again if you run into specific problems.

Comment: You've tagged this question with iphone and objective-c, so I took it for granted you're using objective-c for the iphone. That question you linked to is about c#. objective-c is not c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it:

```
    //
    // Filling first array with 20 elements
    //
    NSMutableArray* arrOne = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];
    NSMutableArray* arrTwo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];

    for (int i=1; i<27; i++) {
        [arrOne addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    }
    //
    // Adding 10 elements starting from initialPosition to second array
    //
    NSLog(@"arrOne: %@", [arrOne componentsJoinedByString:@", "]);
    int initialPosition = 0; // Just change the initial, starting position to 10, 20, 27 and so on..
    [arrTwo addObjectsFromArray:[arrOne objectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(initialPosition, 10)]]];
    NSLog(@"arrTwo: %@", [arrTwo componentsJoinedByString:@", "]);
    [arrOne release];
    [arrTwo release];
```