# Duplicating an array so it becomes unaffected c#

Tags: c#, arrays, copy

I have tried

`int[] secondArray = firstArray;`

but whenever I alter the first array it changes in the second, is there a function that allows me to alter the first without it affecting the second?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to read up on references in .NET.  The code above creates a second instance of the array, but they point to the same location in memory and therefore the same object.   There's a very good article by Jon Skeet here - [References and Values](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html)

Comment: You could loop and add the values of your first array into your second array.  Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733243/how-to-copy-part-of-an-array-to-another-array-in-c to learn about the Array.Copy method, which is probably easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have an object that is an "array of integer" which firstArray references.  Your assignment statement just increments the reference count of the object

I think what you may be looking for is a way to provide a shallow copy of the firstArray?  If so, use the [clone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

Answer (score 2):

Like Tim said, you **need** to understand why this happens, so read up on it. :)

But you could use the [Array.CopyTo method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06x742cw(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int[] firstArray = new int[20];
int[] secondArray = new int[20];
firstArray.CopyTo(secondArray, 0);
```

But you will have to make sure that you wont overflow the second array yourself, because otherwise, it will throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks I am reading up on it now so I understand why and thanks for the input!