# How to loop through and do diffrent statements while a condition is true?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, statements

Is there a way to have diffrent statement for each loop in a while or for loop?
Example: I have an int array, lenght n, and I want to add diffrent specific values (same type of course) at each index ...

so that when index is equal n-1 it stops. I know how to do it if their are a few statements but what if there are 100 specific value to be added.

More specific:

```
public static int[] ArrayPlay(int n) 
{ 
    int[] arr = new int[n]; 
    while (arr[x] < n) 
    arr[0] = 3; 
    arr[1] = 12; 
    arr[2] = 176; 
    arr[3] = 4;
    //so on...
    return arr;
}
```

would look like somthing like this:

```
public static int[] ArrayPlay(int n)//4
{
    int a = 0;
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    while ( a <= n)  //lets say n is 4
        arr[a] = 3;  //arr[0]
    a++;
        arr[a] = 12; //arr[1]
    a++;
        arr[a] = 4;  //arr[2]
    a++;
        arr[a] = 8;  //arr[3] 
    a++;             //(a=4 Stop!  and return arr)
        arr[a] = 7;
    a++;
        arr[a] = 12;
    a++;
        arr[a] = 22;
    a++;
        arr[a] = 18;

    return arr;
}
```

it never passes to a++ because the first statement is Always true.

Is there a way to break, check condition and continue between each statement? 
and what property or method to check an arrays index nr (where I wrote arr[x]) x being the value to be compared with n.

```
public static int[] ArrayPlay2(int n)//4
{

    int[] arr = new int[n];
    for (int a = 0; a < arr.Length; a++)
    {
        arr[a] = 3;  //arr[0]
        arr[a] = 12; //arr[1]
        arr[a] = 4;  //arr[2]
        arr[a] = 8;  //arr[3] (a=4 Stop!  and return arr)
        arr[a] = 7;
        arr[a] = 12;
        arr[a] = 22;
        arr[a] = 18;

    }
    return arr;
}
```

Why dont the code above work??

Comment: What means `there are 100 specific value to be added`? It's simply not clear what you're trying to achieve so it's difficult to help. But what speaks against an `if` or `switch`?

Comment: Don't use arrays.  Instead use List<> where you can just add to the end rather than with arrays where you have to specify the size of the array when it gets constructed.

Comment: Stop talking about loops, if-statements, conditions. Explain in plain english what you want to do.

Comment: I want to fill an array with up to 30 specific values(elements), the amount of elements depends on the int n argument because it decides the length of the array.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're just trying to [copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733243/how-to-copy-part-of-an-array-to-another-array-in-c) part of an array.

```
// TODO: Handle the case "n > magicIntegers.Length" how you see fit.
int[] magicIntegers = new int[] { 3, 12, 4, 8, 7, 12, 22, 18 }; // etc.
int[] copiedArray = new int[n];
return Array.Copy(magicIntegers, 1, b, 0, n);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in your code - while will do only `arr[0] = 3;` or is that what u are trying to do?

If u are trying to loop through all elements why just not use:

```
int[] arr = new int[n];
foreach (int i in arr)
{
}
```

If you are trying to fulfill it than maybe:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
     arr[i] = ...
}
```

I belive you understand it wrong how loop works
all of yours: `arr[a] = 3;  //arr[0]` and `arr[a] = 12; //arr[1]` and `arr[a] = 4;  //arr[2]` are still inside single loop, so a is stil one single number. It is incremented by `a++` that you wrote in `for (int a = 0; a < arr.Length; a++)` part.

Comment: I know, I rewrote my question so it focus on my main issue how to make my condition loop pass arr[0]=3 to a++ and then check condition again and again after each statement.

Comment: Look at my edit It probably explains in what you are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would do some thing like this:

```
// your source array
int[] source = new int[]{3,12,4,8,7,12,22,18}; 
int n = 4; // or what ever  N you want
int[] arr = source.TakeWhile(x => x!=n),ToArray(); // with x!=n as your condition to keep taking
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank u, I didnt find the TakeWhile or Take method in msdn Array class library, i guess they are some kind om interface methods? could u explain (x => x !n) more for me? its a linq?

Comment: Yes, it is a [Lambda](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) Operator, a anonymous function. The syntax is `(input parameters) => expression`, in the TakeWhile the x is the element, so this methode goes through the array testing each element with the Lambda expression until one returns true

Comment: the code above didnt work but the similar code:public static int[] ArrayPlay(int n)
{
    return new []{ 3, 12,4, 8, 7,12,22,18 }
        .Take(n)
        .ToArray();
} 
works, why is that?

Comment: Yeah, my bad. It is the toArray(), the take(n) returns a iEnumrable, not an array

Comment: Yes I added ToArray()   but I am confused why  it only picks out the two first elements 3, 12 if I give argument n=4

Answer (score 0):

You can use a source array which contains all of the possible values and copy only the needed number to a new one.

With linq this is quite easy:

```
public static int[] ArrayPlay(int n)
{
    return new []{ 3, 12,4, 8, 7,12,22,18 }
        .Take(n)
        .ToArray();
}
```

Or you could use [iterators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx) which gives you the values one after the other:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> GetValues()
{
    yield return 3;  //arr[0]
    yield return 12; //arr[1]
    yield return 4;  //arr[2]
    yield return 8;  //arr[3] 
                     //(a=4 Stop!  and return arr)
    yield return 7;
    yield return 12;
    yield return 22;
    yield return 18;
}

public static int[] ArrayPlay(int n)
{
    return GetValues()
        .Take(n)
        .ToArray();
}
```