# Set array values for specific range in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I was looking for a way, how to set specific values for specific range in an array.

Something like this

**Pseudocode:**

```
var s = new uint[64];
s[ 0..15] := { 2, 4, 6, 3,  1, 7, 8, 9,  7, 11, 37, 32,  19, 16, 178, 2200 }
s[16..31] := ...
```

I was trying to find something like this in C#, but with no luck.
I am trying to come with something like this:

```
public void SetArrayValues(int startIndex, uint[] values) 
{
    var length = values.Length;
    this.array[startIndex, startIndex + length] = values;
}
```

The only thing I was able to find was [System.Array.SetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.setvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) but this does not meet my requirements.

Comment: Use List<T>  AddRange() and convert it to array.

Comment: from your example it looks like you are not looking for a range, just for a way to fill array in sequential chunks, and that's much easier I think. @vortex suggested right way for it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy part of an array to another array in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733243/how-to-copy-part-of-an-array-to-another-array-in-c)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the closest you can do is via [`Array.Copy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var s = new uint[64];
uint[] values = { 2, 4, 6, 3, 1, 7, 8, 9, 7, 11, 37, 32, 19, 16, 178, 2200 };

int sourceIndex = 0;
int destinationIndex = 0;
Array.Copy(values, sourceIndex , s, destinationIndex , values.Length);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could write an extension method to make this simpler:

```
public static class ArrayExt
{
    public static T[] Set<T>(this T[] self, int index, params T[] values)
    {
        Array.Copy(values, 0, self, index, values.Length);
        return self;
    }
}
```

Using it would look like this:

```
var s = new uint[64];
s.Set<uint>(0, 2, 4, 6, 3, 1, 7, 8, 9, 7, 11, 37, 32, 19, 16, 178, 2200);
```

Because `Set()` returns the array, you can also chain calls like this:

```
s.Set<uint>( 0, 2, 4, 6, 3, 1, 7, 8, 9, 7, 11, 37, 32, 19, 16, 178, 2200)
 .Set<uint>(16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,  15,   16);
```

Note: The requirement to explicitly put the type into the call comes from the fact that we're using `int`s in the list of values.

You should really use `uint` since the destination is `uint`, then there is no need to specify the type:

```
var s = new uint[64];
s.Set(0, 2u, 4u, 6u, 3u, 1u, 7u, 8u, 9u, 7u, 11u, 37u, 32u, 19u, 16u, 178u, 2200u);
```

And of course it works with all types, e.g. `string`:

```
var x = new string[64];
x.Set(10, "A", "B", "C");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact match to the method you described, but you could create a [`List<int>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and use the `AddRange()` method. Once you've added all the values, you can use to `ToArray()` method to turn it to an array.

```
var numbers = new List<int>();
numbers.AddRange(new List<int>{ 2, 4, 6, 3,  1, 7, 8, 9,  7, 11, 37, 32,  19, 16, 178, 2200 });
//numbers.AddRange(new List<int> { ... });

var asArray = numbers.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a couple ways. Because I do not know you requirements and your code, I know you would need to modify this to suit you. But C# arrays are unlike C++ arrays, so the index always start from zero.

```
UInt64[] list = {2, 4, 6, 3, 1, 7, 8, 9, 7, 11, 37, 32, 19, 16, 178, 2200,..}; 
//Length of the list must be 31. That is contain 31 numbers.

UInt64[] s= new UInt64[31];

// You can have all the collection  

for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
{
    s[i] = list[i];
}    

// Or you can modify as below

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    s[i] = list[i];
}

for (int i = 16; i < 31; i++)
{
    s[i] = list[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you define your Arrays

```
    s1 := { ... }
    s2 := { ... }
    s3 := { ... }
    ...
    sn := { ... }
```

Then just concat them in a linq method chain

`var result = s1.Concat(s2).Concat(s3)....Concat(sn`);

You can do it in whatever order you like and get the exact result. It's easy to change the resulting sequence just by altering the chain slightly.