# How to copy parts of an array to a new array. C#

Tags: c#, arrays

i am trying to copy parts of an array to a new array and searched for a solution, but al those solutions were allot of coding or were not exactly what i was looking for. it might be that i searched wrong on google, but sorry if the answer to this is to easy to find, i couldnt find it.

i have array A

`string[] A = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};`

i tried to copy parts of it to array B using

`string[] B = new string[2];
 Array.Copy(A, 0, B, 0, 2)`

but this just gives a fixed part of array A back so array B consists of "A" and "B".

is there also a way to give array B values 0, 1, 4, 5. so it gives me "A" "B" "E" and "F"

also sorry for bad english it is not my native language, and i tried to search on google for :

allot of the results of my first searches got me to pages about how to get an 2D array but that is not what i need.
"How to copy 2 parts of an array to a new array" what lead me to array.copy tag
after that i tried to look up "array.copy manual" but that only lead me to beleave it cant be done with array.copy so does anyone know how to do this in a compact code?

again. sorry if this answer is to obvious.

Comment: have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733243/how-to-copy-part-of-an-array-to-another-array-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there also a way to give array `B` values 0, 1, 4, 5. so it gives me "A" "B" "E" and "F"

No, because `B` is an array of `string`s. However, you can start with a *separate* array of indexes, and copy from `A` based on them:

```
int[] indexes = new[] {0, 1, 4, 5};
string[] B = indexes.Select(i => A[i]).ToArray();
```

Comment: nice solution. only could be wrong on bound checking. `int[] = new[] { 0,1, 15 };`    might be: `string[] B = indexes.Where(i => i < A.Length).Select(i => A[i]).ToArray();`

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen OP's the one constructing the array of indexes, so observing the proper bounds is on him.

Comment: yours is more profesional it works i found a solution myself just now, but ill use yours and put mine in comment under it for refference purposes thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One way could be:

```
var indices = new[] { 0, 1, 4, 5 };
var copy = A.Where((s, i) => indices.Contains(i)).ToArray();
```

Comment: It's better to use HashSet of indexes, instead of integer array in this case, since Contains is not too fast on an array (full search each time)

Comment: A hashset is not usefull when using 5 items, But I would upgrade it, when I didn't know the numbers.

Comment: Sure, 5 items does not matter. Just thought of a more "generic" case :)

Answer (score 0):

uhm i just went booging arround with my code and this works i guess:

`string[] A = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
 string[] B = new string[4];
 Array.Copy(A, 0, B, 0, 2)
 Array.Copy(A, 4, B, 2, 2)`

it gives array B values A B E and F

Comment: I can hardly believe you can put 4 values in an array of length 3 :)

Comment: oh ye sorry hihi it works it had to be 4 ill edit it.