# Array.Copy vs Buffer.BlockCopy

Tags: .net, arrays

[Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx) and [Buffer.BlockCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx) both do the same thing, but `BlockCopy` is aimed at fast byte-level primitive array copying, whereas `Copy` is the general-purpose implementation. My question is - under what circumstances should you use `BlockCopy`? Should you use it at any time when you are copying primitive type arrays, or should you only use it if you're coding for performance? Is there anything inherently dangerous about using `Buffer.BlockCopy` over `Array.Copy`?

Comment: Don't forget `Marshal.Copy` :-) . Well, use `Array.Copy` for reference types, complex value types and if the type doesn't change, `Buffer.BlockCopy` for "conversion" between value types, byte arrays and byte magic. F.ex. the combination with `StructLayout` is quite powerful if you know what you're doing. As for performance, it seems an unmanaged call to `memcpy`/`cpblk` is the fastest for that - see http://code4k.blogspot.nl/2010/10/high-performance-memcpy-gotchas-in-c.html .

Comment: I did some benchmark tests with `byte[]`. There was no difference in Release version. Sometimes `Array.Copy`, sometimes `Buffer.BlockCopy` (slightly) faster.

Comment: New comprehensive answer just posted below. Note that in cases with small buffer sizes, explicit loop copying is usually best.

Comment: I don't think they do always do the same thing - you can't use Array.Copy to copy an array of Ints to an array of Bytes for instance

Comment: `Array.Copy` is rather a specialized version -- for example it can copy only the same rank arrays.

Comment: [Jon Skeet uses Buffer.BlockCopy.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23413124/145173) That makes it faster. No benchmarking required. :-)

Comment: Did Span<T> change anything in the performance?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Since the parameters to `Buffer.BlockCopy` are byte-based rather than index-based, you're more likely to screw up your code than if you use `Array.Copy`, so I would only use `Buffer.BlockCopy` in a performance-critical section of my code.

Comment: Completely agree.  There's too much room for error with Buffer.BlockCopy.  Keep it simple, and don't try to squeeze any juice out of your program until you know where the juice is (profiling).

Comment: What if you're dealing with a byte[]? Are there any other gotchas with BlockCopy?

Comment: @thecoop: if you're dealing with a byte[] then it's probably fine to use BlockCopy, unless the definition of "byte" is later changed to something other than a byte, which would probably have a pretty negative effect on other parts of your code anyway. :) The only other potential gotcha is that BlockCopy just does straight bytes, so it doesn't take endianness into account, but this would only come into play on a non-Windows machine, and only if you'd screwed up the code in the first place. Also, there might be some weird difference if you're using mono.

Comment: Do we have numbers to compare Array.Copy vs BUffer.BlockCopy?

Comment: In my own testing, Array.Copy() is very similar in performance to Buffer.BlockCopy(). Buffer.BlockCopy is consistently < 10% faster for me when dealing with 640 element byte arrays (which is the sort I'm most interested in). But you should do your own testing with your own data, because it'll presumably vary depending on the data, data types, array sizes, and so forth. I should note that both methods are roughly 3x faster than using Array.Clone(), and maybe 20x faster than copying it in a for loop.

Comment: @Ken Smith: OK, I give - why are you interested in 640 element byte arrays?

Comment: @MusiGenesis - That's the size of 16-bit audio, sampled at 16 Khz, transmitted 20ms at a time. I'm largely responsible for the client-side media stack that http://alanta.com/ uses for transmitting audio and video from Silverlight, and I've spent a lot of time trying to optimize that chunk of the code. When you're creating and destroying and analyzing and copying hundreds of byte arrays every second, micro-optimizations actually start to make sense.

Comment: @Ken: I hear you - I write software synthesizers myself, although I would turn up my nose at a 16 Khz sample rate. :)

Comment: @MusiGenesis , I'm pretty sure BlockCopy will give you problems with byte[] because when I tried to use it with UInt16[], I got undesired results. It appeared to only copy half of the designated range, but I assume it was implicitly converting to Int32 and back since the MSDN specification for BlockCopy only refers to 32-bit primitive datatypes. I changed to Array.Copy and it worked as expected.

Comment: @KevinMiller: uh, `UInt16` is two bytes per element. If you pass this array to BlockCopy along with the number of elements in the array, of course only half the array will be copied. For this to work properly, you would need to pass the number of elements *times* the size of each element (2) as the length parameter. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy(v=vs.110).aspx and search for `INT_SIZE` in the examples.

Comment: I just ran into this difference when trying to copy an array of characters stored in bytes into a 'char' array which is 16bits.  Array.copy resolves correctly whereas blockcopy gives me chinese characters :)

Answer (score 179):

**Prelude**

I'm joining the party late, but with 32k views, it's worth getting this right. Most of the microbenchmarking code in the posted answers thus far suffer from one or more severe technical flaws, including not moving memory allocations out of the test loops (which introduces severe GC artifacts), not testing variable vs. deterministic execution flows, JIT warmup, and not tracking intra-test variability. In addition, most answers did not test the effects of varying buffer sizes and varying primitive types (with respect to either 32-bit or 64-bit systems). To address this question more comprehensively, I hooked it up to a custom microbenchmarking framework I developed that reduces most of the common "gotchas" to the extent possible. Tests were run in .NET 4.0 Release mode on both a 32-bit machine and a 64-bit machine. Results were averaged over 20 testing runs, in which each run had 1 million trials per method. Primitive types tested were `byte` (1 byte), `int` (4 bytes), and `double` (8 bytes). Three methods were tested: `Array.Copy()`, `Buffer.BlockCopy()`, and simple per-index assignment in a loop. The data is too voluminous to post here, so I will summarize the important points.

**The Takeaways**

- If your buffer length is about 75-100 or less, an explicit loop copy routine is usually faster (by about 5%) than either `Array.Copy()` or `Buffer.BlockCopy()` for all 3 primitive types tested on both 32-bit and 64-bit machines. Additionly, the explicit loop copy routine has noticeably lower variability in performance compared to the two alternatives. The good performance is almost surely due to [locality of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference#Hierarchical_memory) exploited by CPU L1/L2/L3 memory caching in conjunction with no method call overhead.

  - For `double` buffers ***on 32-bit machines only**:* The explicit loop copy routine is better than both alternatives for all buffer sizes tested up to 100k. The improvement is 3-5% better than the other methods. This is because the performance of `Array.Copy()` and `Buffer.BlockCopy()` become totally degraded upon passing the native 32-bit width. Thus I assume the same effect would apply to `long` buffers as well.
- For buffer sizes exceeding ~100, explicit loop copying quickly becomes much slower than the other 2 methods (with the one particular exception just noted). The difference is most noticeable with `byte[]`, where explicit loop copying can become 7x or more slower at large buffer sizes.
- In general, for all 3 primitive types tested and across all buffer sizes, `Array.Copy()` and `Buffer.BlockCopy()` performed almost identically. On average, `Array.Copy()` seems to have a very slight edge of about 2% or less time taken (but 0.2% - 0.5% better is typical), although `Buffer.BlockCopy()` did occasionally beat it. For unknown reasons, `Buffer.BlockCopy()` has noticeably higher intra-test variability than `Array.Copy()`. This effect could not be eliminated despite me trying multiple mitigations and not having an operable theory on why.
- Because `Array.Copy()` is a "smarter", more general, and much safer method, in addition to being very slightly faster and having less variability on average, it should be preferred to `Buffer.BlockCopy()` in almost all common cases. The only use case where `Buffer.BlockCopy()` will be significantly better is when the source and destination array value types are different (as pointed out in Ken Smith's answer). While this scenario is not common, `Array.Copy()` can perform very poorly here due to the continual "safe" value type casting, compared to the direct casting of `Buffer.BlockCopy()`.
- Additional evidence from outside StackOverflow that `Array.Copy()` is faster than `Buffer.BlockCopy()` for same-type array copying can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/65183/Buffer-BlockCopy-not-as-fast-as-you-think).

Comment: As an aside, it also turns out that around an array length of 100 is when .NET's `Array.Clear()` first begins to beat an explicit loop assignment clearing of an array (setting to `false`, `0`, or `null`). This is consistent with my similar findings above. These separate benchmarks were discovered online here: http://manski.net/2012/12/net-array-clear-vs-arrayx-0-performance/

Comment: When you say buffer size; do you mean in bytes, or element count?

Comment: In my above answer, both "buffer length" and "buffer size" generally refer to element count.

Comment: I have an example where I need to frequently copy about 8 bytes of data into a buffer reading from a source offset by 5 bytes.  I found the explicit loop copy to be significantly faster then use Buffer.BlockCopy or Array.Copy.  ```Loop Results for 1000000 iterations 17.9515ms.
Buffer.BlockCopy Results for 1000000 iterations 39.8937ms.
Array.Copy Results for 1000000 iterations 45.9059ms```  However, if the copy size > ~20 bytes the explicit loop is significantly slower.

Comment: @TodCunningham, 8 bytes of data? You mean long equivalent? Either cast and copy single element (dead fast) or simply unroll that loop manually.

Comment: @astrowalker It was CAN data which could vary in length.  The main point here is that a brute force copy can be significantly faster then BlockCopy for small buffers which is interesting.

Comment: @TodCunningham, you mentioned "source offset by 5 bytes". `Array.Copy` and `Buffer.BlockCopy` are strongest when they can operate on machine-word and/or page boundaries. On a 64 bit machine that'll be 4 bytes boundaries. Furthermore, as shown in this post, the overhead of the method call, plus bounds checking, and the lack of locality makes `Array.Copy` a pretty bad choice for small arrays (< 100 or so items). An (unrolled) loop with bounds-checking off will be much faster, as you also found.

Comment: Interesting answer. Since it was written in 2015 though, I added a new answer with results for .NET 5.

Answer (score 70):

Another example of when it makes sense to use `Buffer.BlockCopy()` is when you're provided with an array of primitives (say, shorts), and need to convert it to an array of bytes (say, for transmission over a network).  I use this method frequently when dealing with audio from the Silverlight AudioSink.  It provides the sample as a `short[]` array, but you need to convert it to a `byte[]` array when you're building the packet that you submit to `Socket.SendAsync()`.  You could use `BitConverter`, and iterate through the array one-by-one, but it's a lot faster (about 20x in my testing) just to do this:

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(shortSamples, 0, packetBytes, 0, shortSamples.Length * sizeof(short)).
```

And the same trick works in reverse as well:

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(packetBytes, readPosition, shortSamples, 0, payloadLength);
```

This is about as close as you get in safe C# to the `(void *)` sort of memory management that's so common in C and C++.

Comment: That's a cool idea - do you ever run into issues with endianness?

Comment: Yeah, I think that you could run into that problem, depending on your scenario. My own scenarios have typically been either (a) I need to switch back-and-forth between byte arrays and short arrays on the same machine, or (b) I happen to know that I'm sending my data to machines of the same endianness, and which I control the remote side. But if you were using a protocol for which the remote machine expected data to be sent in network order rather than host order, yeah, this approach would give you problems.

Comment: Ken also has an article about BlockCopy on his blog: http://blog.wouldbetheologian.com/2011/11/my-favorite-c-micro-optimization-1.html

Comment: Note that since .Net Core 2.1 you can do this without copying. `MemoryMarshal.AsBytes<T>` or `MemoryMarshal.Cast<TFrom, TTo>` let you interpret your sequence of one primitive as a sequene of another primitive.

Comment: I have an array of shorts in my bottom drawer.

Answer (score 17):

Based on my testing, performance is *not* a reason to prefer Buffer.BlockCopy over Array.Copy.  From my testing Array.Copy is actually *faster* than Buffer.BlockCopy.

```
var buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(...);

var length = buffer.Length;
var copy = new byte[length];

var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

TimeSpan blockCopyTotal = TimeSpan.Zero, arrayCopyTotal = TimeSpan.Zero;

const int times = 20;

for (int i = 0; i < times; ++i)
{
    stopwatch.Start();
    Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, copy, 0, length);
    stopwatch.Stop();

    blockCopyTotal += stopwatch.Elapsed;

    stopwatch.Reset();

    stopwatch.Start();
    Array.Copy(buffer, 0, copy, 0, length);
    stopwatch.Stop();

    arrayCopyTotal += stopwatch.Elapsed;

    stopwatch.Reset();
}

Console.WriteLine("bufferLength: {0}", length);
Console.WriteLine("BlockCopy: {0}", blockCopyTotal);
Console.WriteLine("ArrayCopy: {0}", arrayCopyTotal);
Console.WriteLine("BlockCopy (average): {0}", TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(blockCopyTotal.TotalMilliseconds / times));
Console.WriteLine("ArrayCopy (average): {0}", TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(arrayCopyTotal.TotalMilliseconds / times));
```

Example Output:

```
bufferLength: 396011520
BlockCopy: 00:00:02.0441855
ArrayCopy: 00:00:01.8876299
BlockCopy (average): 00:00:00.1020000
ArrayCopy (average): 00:00:00.0940000
```

Comment: Sorry about this answer being more of a comment, but it was too long for a comment.  Since the consensus seemed to be that Buffer.BlockCopy was better for performace, I thought everyone should be aware that I was not able to confirm that consensus with testing.

Comment: I think there's a problem with your testing methodology. Most of the time difference you're noting is the result of the application spinning up, caching itself, running the JIT, that sort of thing. Try it with a smaller buffer, but a few thousand times; and then repeat the whole test within a loop half a dozen times, and only pay attention to the last run.  My own testing has Buffer.BlockCopy() running maybe 5% faster than Array.Copy() for 640 byte arrays. Not much faster, but a little.

Comment: I measured the same for a specific problem, I could see **no performance difference between Array.Copy() and Buffer.BlockCopy()**. If anything, _BlockCopy introduced unsafey which actually killed my app_ in one instance.

Comment: Just like to add Array.Copy supports long for the source position so breaking into *big* byte arrays it won't throw an out of range exception.

Comment: Based on the test's I've just made (https://bitbucket.org/breki74/tutis/commits/cffbddfdec985a66c1e71bf11044dd665c2fa690) I would say there's no practical performance difference between the two methods when you're dealing with byte arrays.

Answer (score 7):

ArrayCopy is smarter than BlockCopy. It figures out how to copy elements if the source and destination are the same array.

If we populate an int array with 0,1,2,3,4 and apply:

```
Array.Copy(array, 0, array, 1, array.Length - 1);
```

we end up with 0,0,1,2,3 as expected.

Try this with BlockCopy and we get: 0,0,2,3,4. If I assign `array[0]=-1` after that, it becomes -1,0,2,3,4 as expected, but if the array length is even, like 6, we get -1,256,2,3,4,5. Dangerous stuff. Don't use BlockCopy other than for copying one byte array into another.

There is another case where you can only use Array.Copy: if the array size is longer than 2^31. Array.Copy has an overload with a `long` size parameter. BlockCopy does not have that.

Comment: The results of your tests with BlockCopy are not unexpected. It's because Block copy tries to copy chunks of data at a time rather than one byte at a time. On a 32 bit system it copies 4 bytes at a time, on a 64 bit system it copies 8 bytes at a time.

Comment: So expected undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5):

On .NET 5.0.6 (x64) - for copying byte array to byte array - `Array.Copy` seems to be the winner even for short arrays. Interestingly enough `Enumumerable.Concat` is also relatively fast on longer arrays because it optimizes for `ICollection<T>` if enumerable implements it (it is not the case for .NET Framework though).

Benchmark results and source code:

| Method | ArrayLength | NumberOfArrays | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **EnumerableConcat** | **50** | **1** | **63.54 ns** | **1.863 ns** | **5.435 ns** |
| ForLoop | 50 | 1 | 95.01 ns | 2.008 ns | 4.694 ns |
| ForeachLoop | 50 | 1 | 91.80 ns | 1.953 ns | 4.527 ns |
| ArrayCopy | 50 | 1 | 26.66 ns | 1.043 ns | 3.075 ns |
| BufferBlockCopy | 50 | 1 | 27.65 ns | 0.716 ns | 2.076 ns |
| **EnumerableConcat** | **50** | **2** | **265.30 ns** | **9.362 ns** | **26.558 ns** |
| ForLoop | 50 | 2 | 188.80 ns | 5.084 ns | 13.659 ns |
| ForeachLoop | 50 | 2 | 180.16 ns | 4.953 ns | 14.448 ns |
| ArrayCopy | 50 | 2 | 42.47 ns | 0.970 ns | 2.623 ns |
| BufferBlockCopy | 50 | 2 | 47.28 ns | 1.038 ns | 2.024 ns |
| **EnumerableConcat** | **50** | **3** | **327.81 ns** | **9.332 ns** | **27.368 ns** |
| ForLoop | 50 | 3 | 285.21 ns | 6.028 ns | 17.680 ns |
| ForeachLoop | 50 | 3 | 260.04 ns | 5.308 ns | 14.795 ns |
| ArrayCopy | 50 | 3 | 62.97 ns | 1.505 ns | 4.366 ns |
| BufferBlockCopy | 50 | 3 | 73.45 ns | 3.265 ns | 9.626 ns |
| **EnumerableConcat** | **100** | **1** | **69.27 ns** | **1.762 ns** | **5.167 ns** |
| ForLoop | 100 | 1 | 189.44 ns | 3.907 ns | 11.398 ns |
| ForeachLoop | 100 | 1 | 163.03 ns | 3.311 ns | 5.057 ns |
| ArrayCopy | 100 | 1 | 33.23 ns | 1.225 ns | 3.574 ns |
| BufferBlockCopy | 100 | 1 | 35.55 ns | 1.004 ns | 2.865 ns |
| **EnumerableConcat** | **100** | **2** | **291.20 ns** | **10.245 ns** | **30.207 ns** |
| ForLoop | 100 | 2 | 363.01 ns | 7.160 ns | 9.310 ns |
| ForeachLoop | 100 | 2 | 357.98 ns | 7.228 ns | 7.734 ns |
| ArrayCopy | 100 | 2 | 56.59 ns | 1.702 ns | 5.019 ns |
| BufferBlockCopy | 100 | 2 | 61.82 ns | 1.747 ns | 5.095 ns |
| **EnumerableConcat** | **100** | **3** | **354.19 ns** | **9.679 ns** | **27.925 ns** |
| ForLoop | 100 | 3 | 544.59 ns | 16.346 ns | 48.198 ns |
| ForeachLoop | 100 | 3 | 522.59 ns | 12.927 ns | 37.914 ns |
| ArrayCopy | 100 | 3 | 80.66 ns | 3.154 ns | 9.300 ns |
| BufferBlockCopy | 100 | 3 | 87.21 ns | 2.414 ns | 7.081 ns |
| **EnumerableConcat** | **1000** | **1** | **181.98 ns** | **4.073 ns** | **11.882 ns** |
| ForLoop | 1000 | 1 | 1,643.59 ns | 32.135 ns | 50.030 ns |
| ForeachLoop | 1000 | 1 | 1,444.37 ns | 28.705 ns | 70.951 ns |
| ArrayCopy | 1000 | 1 | 143.55 ns | 3.874 ns | 11.301 ns |
| BufferBlockCopy | 1000 | 1 | 146.69 ns | 3.349 ns | 9.662 ns |
| **EnumerableConcat** | **1000** | **2** | **525.41 ns** | **10.621 ns** | **29.254 ns** |
| ForLoop | 1000 | 2 | 3,264.64 ns | 47.449 ns | 39.622 ns |
| ForeachLoop | 1000 | 2 | 2,818.58 ns | 56.489 ns | 126.345 ns |
| ArrayCopy | 1000 | 2 | 283.73 ns | 5.613 ns | 15.175 ns |
| BufferBlockCopy | 1000 | 2 | 292.29 ns | 5.827 ns | 15.654 ns |
| **EnumerableConcat** | **1000** | **3** | **712.58 ns** | **15.274 ns** | **44.068 ns** |
| ForLoop | 1000 | 3 | 5,005.50 ns | 99.791 ns | 214.810 ns |
| ForeachLoop | 1000 | 3 | 4,272.26 ns | 89.589 ns | 261.335 ns |
| ArrayCopy | 1000 | 3 | 422.30 ns | 8.542 ns | 22.502 ns |
| BufferBlockCopy | 1000 | 3 | 433.49 ns | 8.808 ns | 20.587 ns |
| **EnumerableConcat** | **10000** | **1** | **1,221.27 ns** | **28.138 ns** | **82.964 ns** |
| ForLoop | 10000 | 1 | 16,464.04 ns | 441.552 ns | 1,294.995 ns |
| ForeachLoop | 10000 | 1 | 13,916.99 ns | 273.792 ns | 676.746 ns |
| ArrayCopy | 10000 | 1 | 1,150.18 ns | 26.901 ns | 79.318 ns |
| BufferBlockCopy | 10000 | 1 | 1,154.10 ns | 23.094 ns | 60.025 ns |
| **EnumerableConcat** | **10000** | **2** | **2,798.41 ns** | **54.615 ns** | **141.952 ns** |
| ForLoop | 10000 | 2 | 32,570.61 ns | 646.828 ns | 1,473.154 ns |
| ForeachLoop | 10000 | 2 | 27,707.12 ns | 545.888 ns | 1,051.741 ns |
| ArrayCopy | 10000 | 2 | 2,379.49 ns | 72.264 ns | 213.073 ns |
| BufferBlockCopy | 10000 | 2 | 2,374.17 ns | 59.035 ns | 173.140 ns |
| **EnumerableConcat** | **10000** | **3** | **3,885.27 ns** | **77.809 ns** | **196.633 ns** |
| ForLoop | 10000 | 3 | 49,833.15 ns | 984.022 ns | 2,097.031 ns |
| ForeachLoop | 10000 | 3 | 41,174.21 ns | 819.971 ns | 1,392.373 ns |
| ArrayCopy | 10000 | 3 | 3,738.32 ns | 74.331 ns | 91.285 ns |
| BufferBlockCopy | 10000 | 3 | 3,839.79 ns | 78.865 ns | 231.298 ns |

```
public class ArrayConcatBenchmark
{
    [Params(50, 100, 1000, 10000)]
    public int ArrayLength;

    [Params(1, 2, 3)]
    public int NumberOfArrays;

    private byte[][] data;

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void GlobalSetup()
    {
        data = new byte[NumberOfArrays][];
        var random = new Random(42);
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfArrays; i++)
        {
            data[i] = new byte[ArrayLength];
            random.NextBytes(data[i]);
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public byte[] EnumerableConcat()
    {
        IEnumerable<byte> enumerable = data[0];

        for (int n = 1; n < NumberOfArrays; n++)
        {
            enumerable = enumerable.Concat(data[n]);
        }

        return enumerable.ToArray();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public byte[] ForLoop()
    {
        var result = new byte[ArrayLength * NumberOfArrays];

        for (int n = 0; n < NumberOfArrays; n++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ArrayLength; i++)
            {
                result[i + n * ArrayLength] = data[n][i];
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public byte[] ForeachLoop()
    {
        var result = new byte[ArrayLength * NumberOfArrays];

        for (int n = 0; n < NumberOfArrays; n++)
        {
            int i = 0;

            foreach (var item in data[n])
            {
                result[i + n * ArrayLength] = item;
                i++;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public byte[] ArrayCopy()
    {
        var result = new byte[ArrayLength * NumberOfArrays];

        for (int n = 0; n < NumberOfArrays; n++)
        {
            Array.Copy(data[n], 0, result, n * ArrayLength, ArrayLength);
        }

        return result;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public byte[] BufferBlockCopy()
    {
        var result = new byte[ArrayLength * NumberOfArrays];

        for (int n = 0; n < NumberOfArrays; n++)
        {
            Buffer.BlockCopy(data[n], 0, result, n * ArrayLength, ArrayLength);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Are all results the same: " + AreAllResultsTheSame());
        BenchmarkRunner.Run<ArrayConcatBenchmark>();
    }

    private static bool AreAllResultsTheSame()
    {
        var ac = new ArrayConcatBenchmark()
        {
            NumberOfArrays = 2,
            ArrayLength = 100,
        };

        ac.GlobalSetup();

        var firstResult = ac.EnumerableConcat();
        var otherResults = new[]
        {
            ac.ForLoop(),
            ac.ForeachLoop(),
            ac.ArrayCopy(),
            ac.BufferBlockCopy(),
        };

        return otherResults.All(x => firstResult.SequenceEqual(x));
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that the `ArrayCopy` performs better than the `BufferBlockCopy` (except in the 1000 length and 2 array setup). It is tested in .NET 5, do you know if the performance holds in other .NET framework? I am especially interested in .NET Standard.

Comment: I didn't test on other .NET versions - the test code is there for you to test in your environment :)

Answer (score 2):

To weigh in on this argument, if one is not careful how they author this benchmark they could be easily misled. I wrote a very simple test to illustrate this. In my test below if I swap the order of my tests between starting Buffer.BlockCopy first or Array.Copy the one that goes first is almost always the slowest (although its a close one). This means for a bunch of reasons which I wont go into simply running the tests multiple times esp one after the other will not give accurate results.

I resorted to maintaining the test as is  with 1000000 tries each for an array of 1000000 sequential doubles. However in I then disregard the first 900000 cycles and average the remainder. In that case the Buffer is superior.

```
private static void BenchmarkArrayCopies()
        {
            long[] bufferRes = new long[1000000];
            long[] arrayCopyRes = new long[1000000];
            long[] manualCopyRes = new long[1000000];

            double[] src = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).Select(x => (double)x).ToArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                bufferRes[i] = ArrayCopyTests.ArrayBufferBlockCopy(src).Ticks;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                arrayCopyRes[i] = ArrayCopyTests.ArrayCopy(src).Ticks;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                manualCopyRes[i] = ArrayCopyTests.ArrayManualCopy(src).Ticks;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Loop Copy: {0}", manualCopyRes.Average());
            Console.WriteLine("Array.Copy Copy: {0}", arrayCopyRes.Average());
            Console.WriteLine("Buffer.BlockCopy Copy: {0}", bufferRes.Average());

            //more accurate results - average last 1000

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("----More accurate comparisons----");

            Console.WriteLine("Loop Copy: {0}", manualCopyRes.Where((l, i) => i > 900000).ToList().Average());
            Console.WriteLine("Array.Copy Copy: {0}", arrayCopyRes.Where((l, i) => i > 900000).ToList().Average());
            Console.WriteLine("Buffer.BlockCopy Copy: {0}", bufferRes.Where((l, i) => i > 900000).ToList().Average());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

public class ArrayCopyTests
    {
        private const int byteSize = sizeof(double);

        public static TimeSpan ArrayBufferBlockCopy(double[] original)
        {
            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            double[] copy = new double[original.Length];
            watch.Start();
            Buffer.BlockCopy(original, 0 * byteSize, copy, 0 * byteSize, original.Length * byteSize);
            watch.Stop();
            return watch.Elapsed;
        }

        public static TimeSpan ArrayCopy(double[] original)
        {
            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            double[] copy = new double[original.Length];
            watch.Start();
            Array.Copy(original, 0, copy, 0, original.Length);
            watch.Stop();
            return watch.Elapsed;
        }

        public static TimeSpan ArrayManualCopy(double[] original)
        {
            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            double[] copy = new double[original.Length];
            watch.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < original.Length; i++)
            {
                copy[i] = original[i];
            }
            watch.Stop();
            return watch.Elapsed;
        }
    }
```

https://github.com/chivandikwa/Random-Benchmarks

Comment: I don't see any timing results in your answer. Please include the console output.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add my testing case which shows again BlockCopy has no 'PERFORMANCE' benefit over Array.Copy. They seem to have the same performance under release mode on my machine (both take about 66ms to copy 50 million integers). Under debug mode, BlockCopy is just marginally faster.

```
    private static T[] CopyArray<T>(T[] a) where T:struct 
    {
        T[] res = new T[a.Length];
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
        DateTime time1 = DateTime.Now;
        Buffer.BlockCopy(a,0,res,0, size*a.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Using Buffer blockcopy: {0}", (DateTime.Now - time1).Milliseconds);
        return res;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int simulation_number = 50000000;
        int[] testarray1 = new int[simulation_number];

        int begin = 0;
        Random r = new Random();
        while (begin != simulation_number)
        {
            testarray1[begin++] = r.Next(0, 10000);
        }

        var copiedarray = CopyArray(testarray1);

        var testarray2 = new int[testarray1.Length];
        DateTime time2 = DateTime.Now;
        Array.Copy(testarray1, testarray2, testarray1.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Using Array.Copy(): {0}", (DateTime.Now - time2).Milliseconds);
    }
```

Comment: No offence but your test result isn't really helpful ;) First of all "20ms faster" tells you nothing without knowing the overall time. You also carried out those two test in a very differeny manner. The BlockCopy case has an additional method call and the allocation of your target array which you don't have in your Array.Copy case. Due to multithreading fluctuations (possible task switch, core switch) you can easily get different results everytime you execute the test.

Comment: @Bunny83 thanks for the comment. I have slightly modified the timer location which should give a fairer comparison now. And I am a bit surprised that blockcopy is not faster than array.copy at all.