# FIFO/Queue buffer specialising in byte streams

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, data-stream

Is there any .NET data structure/combination of classes that allows for byte data to be appended to the end of a buffer but all peeks and reads are from the start, shortening the buffer when I read?

The `MemoryStream` class seems to do part of this, but I need to maintain separate locations for reading and writing, and it doesn't automatically discard the data at the start after it's read.

An answer has been posted in reply to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122972/buffering-byte-data-in-c-sharp) which is basically what I'm trying to do but I'd prefer something I can do asynchronous I/O on in different components of the same process, just like a normal pipe or even a network stream (I need to filter/process the data first).

Comment: Is there something wrong with jumping back and forth inside a read buffer?

Comment: Only what I said and having to keep track of that as opposed to the NetworkStream style of read, read, read, etc.

Comment: Do you need to read and write arrays of different sizes? Wouldn't a queue of `byte[]` be good enough for you?

Comment: Reads will be individual bytes until I find certain data then various length chunks. Writes will be any length depending on what data I receive.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll post a stripped out copy of some logic i wrote for a project at work once. The advantage of this version is that it works with a linked list of buffered data and therefore you dont have to cache huge amounts of memory and/or copy memory around when reading. furthermore, its thread safe and behaves like a network stream, that is: When reading when there is no data available: Wait untill there is data available or timeout. Also, when reading x amounts of bytes and there are only y amounts of bytes, return after reading all bytes. I hope this helps!

```
    public class SlidingStream : Stream
{
    #region Other stream member implementations

    ...

    #endregion Other stream member implementations

    public SlidingStream()
    {
        ReadTimeout = -1;
    }

    private readonly object _writeSyncRoot = new object();
    private readonly object _readSyncRoot = new object();
    private readonly LinkedList<ArraySegment<byte>> _pendingSegments = new LinkedList<ArraySegment<byte>>();
    private readonly ManualResetEventSlim _dataAvailableResetEvent = new ManualResetEventSlim();

    public int ReadTimeout { get; set; }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (_dataAvailableResetEvent.Wait(ReadTimeout))
            throw new TimeoutException("No data available");

        lock (_readSyncRoot)
        {
            int currentCount = 0;
            int currentOffset = 0;

            while (currentCount != count)
            {
                ArraySegment<byte> segment = _pendingSegments.First.Value;
                _pendingSegments.RemoveFirst();

                int index = segment.Offset;
                for (; index < segment.Count; index++)
                {
                    if (currentOffset < offset)
                    {
                        currentOffset++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        buffer[currentCount] = segment.Array[index];
                        currentCount++;
                    }
                }

                if (currentCount == count)
                {
                    if (index < segment.Offset + segment.Count)
                    {
                        _pendingSegments.AddFirst(new ArraySegment<byte>(segment.Array, index, segment.Offset + segment.Count - index));
                    }
                }

                if (_pendingSegments.Count == 0)
                {
                    _dataAvailableResetEvent.Reset();

                    return currentCount;
                }
            }

            return currentCount;
        }
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        lock (_writeSyncRoot)
        {
            byte[] copy = new byte[count];
            Array.Copy(buffer, offset, copy, 0, count);

            _pendingSegments.AddLast(new ArraySegment<byte>(copy));

            _dataAvailableResetEvent.Set();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good, and was the way same I was heading. I'll try it tonight.

Comment: It seems to me this will crash if you try to read data when none is available.

Comment: @svick - Absolutely right, its just a draft, no argument validation etc. The manualResetEvent is there for that sole reason, i just forgot to wait on it in the beginning of the read method. Fixed now. Thanks for the headsup

Comment: Any ideas for hinting EOS to elegantly return 0 to the reader (instead of the nasty timeout exception)?

Comment: This looks really good. I was planning to do something like this, but I googled it first.
@Deanna Have you published your derative somewhere? Could you do it?
It would be nice to see what you did with it.
Exception handling etc

Comment: I found this one also. It's C# although the link starts with "java".
http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/File-Stream/FifoStream.htm

Comment: I'll see if I can find it still... It was a toy project many years ago, and its been 18 months since I did any .net work :)

Comment: This also has a race condition in it - what happens if the writing thread sets the 'data available' event just before the reader resets it?

Comment: @JasonHolloway The next Write() will fix that. If there is no Write() (I.e. end-of-stream) then you can set the 'data available' in the Dispose() maybe

Answer (score 1):

The code can be simpler than in the accepted answer. There is no need to use a `for` loop.:

```
/// <summary>
/// This class is a very fast and threadsafe FIFO buffer
/// </summary>
public class FastFifo
{
    private List<Byte> mi_FifoData = new List<Byte>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the count of bytes in the Fifo buffer
    /// </summary>
    public int Count
    {
        get 
        { 
            lock (mi_FifoData)
            {
                return mi_FifoData.Count; 
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clears the Fifo buffer
    /// </summary>
    public void Clear()
    {
        lock (mi_FifoData)
        {
            mi_FifoData.Clear();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Append data to the end of the fifo
    /// </summary>
    public void Push(Byte[] u8_Data)
    {
        lock (mi_FifoData)
        {
            // Internally the .NET framework uses Array.Copy() which is extremely fast
            mi_FifoData.AddRange(u8_Data);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get data from the beginning of the fifo.
    /// returns null if s32_Count bytes are not yet available.
    /// </summary>
    public Byte[] Pop(int s32_Count)
    {
        lock (mi_FifoData)
        {
            if (mi_FifoData.Count < s32_Count)
                return null;

            // Internally the .NET framework uses Array.Copy() which is extremely fast
            Byte[] u8_PopData = new Byte[s32_Count];
            mi_FifoData.CopyTo(0, u8_PopData, 0, s32_Count);
            mi_FifoData.RemoveRange(0, s32_Count);
            return u8_PopData;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a byte without removing it from the Fifo buffer
    /// returns -1 if the index is invalid
    /// </summary>
    public int PeekAt(int s32_Index)
    {
        lock (mi_FifoData)
        {
            if (s32_Index < 0 || s32_Index >= mi_FifoData.Count)
                return -1;

            return mi_FifoData[s32_Index];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's essentially the same as the linked question, which doesn't fulfil the asynchronous or blocking desires . Thanks though.

Comment: OK, but that code is not so elegant and it is not thread safe. You can do it with 6 lines rather than  needing 16 lines.

Answer (score 0):

I tried polishing Polity's code. It's far from optimization, but maybe just works.

```
public class SlidingStream : Stream {
  public SlidingStream() {
    ReadTimeout = -1;
  }

  private readonly object ReadSync = new object();
  private readonly object WriteSync = new object();
  private readonly ConcurrentQueue<ArraySegment<byte>> PendingSegments
    = new ConcurrentQueue<ArraySegment<byte>>();
  private readonly ManualResetEventSlim DataAvailable = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
  private ArraySegment<byte>? PartialSegment;

  public new int ReadTimeout;

  public override bool CanRead => true;

  public override bool CanSeek => false;

  public override bool CanWrite => true;

  public override long Length => throw new NotImplementedException();

  public override long Position {
    get => throw new NotImplementedException();
    set => throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  private bool Closed;

  public override void Close() {
    Closed = true;
    DataAvailable.Set();
    base.Close();
  }

  public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) {
    int msStart = Environment.TickCount;

    lock (ReadSync) {
      int read = 0;

      while (read < count) {
        ArraySegment<byte>? seg = TryDequeue(msStart);
        if (seg == null) {
          return read;
        }

        ArraySegment<byte> segment = seg.GetValueOrDefault();
        int bite = Math.Min(count - read, segment.Count);
        if (bite < segment.Count) {
          PartialSegment = new ArraySegment<byte>(
            segment.Array,
            segment.Offset + bite,
            segment.Count - bite
          );
        }

        Array.Copy(segment.Array, segment.Offset, buffer, offset + read, bite);
        read += bite;
      }

      return read;
    }
  }

  private ArraySegment<byte>? TryDequeue(int msStart) {
    ArraySegment<byte>? ps = PartialSegment;
    if (ps.HasValue) {
      PartialSegment = null;
      return ps;
    }

    DataAvailable.Reset();

    ArraySegment<byte> segment;
    while (!PendingSegments.TryDequeue(out segment)) {
      if (Closed) {
        return null;
      }
      WaitDataOrTimeout(msStart);
    }

    return segment;
  }

  private void WaitDataOrTimeout(int msStart) {
    int timeout;
    if (ReadTimeout == -1) {
      timeout = -1;
    }
    else {
      timeout = msStart + ReadTimeout - Environment.TickCount;
    }

    if (!DataAvailable.Wait(timeout)) {
      throw new TimeoutException("No data available");
    }
  }

  public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) {
    lock (WriteSync) {
      byte[] copy = new byte[count];
      Array.Copy(buffer, offset, copy, 0, count);

      PendingSegments.Enqueue(new ArraySegment<byte>(copy));

      DataAvailable.Set();
    }
  }

  public override void Flush() {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  public override void SetLength(long value) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And here's a hopefully race condition free version using `SemaphoreSlim` to notify:

```
public class SlidingStream : Stream
{
    private readonly object _writeLock = new object();
    private readonly object _readLock = new object();
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> _pendingSegments = new ConcurrentQueue<byte[]>();
    private byte[] _extraSegment = null;

    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _smSegmentsAvailable = new SemaphoreSlim(0);

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        lock (_writeLock)
        {
            var copy = new byte[count];
            Array.Copy(buffer, offset, copy, 0, count);

            _pendingSegments.Enqueue(copy);
            _smSegmentsAvailable.Release(1);
        }
    }

    public override Task WriteAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancel)
    {
        Write(buffer, offset, count);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int bytesToRead)
    {
        lock (_readLock)
        {
            var bytesRead = 0;

            while (bytesToRead > 0)
            {
                byte[] segment;

                if (_extraSegment != null)
                {
                    segment = _extraSegment;
                    _extraSegment = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (_smSegmentsAvailable.CurrentCount == 0 && bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        return bytesRead;
                    }

                    _smSegmentsAvailable.Wait(_cancel);

                    if (!_pendingSegments.TryDequeue(out segment))
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("No segment found, despite semaphore");
                    }
                }

                var copyCount = Math.Min(bytesToRead, segment.Length);
                Array.Copy(segment, 0, buffer, offset + bytesRead, copyCount);
                bytesToRead -= copyCount;
                bytesRead += copyCount;

                var extraCount = segment.Length - copyCount;
                if (extraCount > 0)
                {
                    _extraSegment = new byte[extraCount];
                    Array.Copy(segment, copyCount, _extraSegment, 0, extraCount);
                }
            }

            return bytesRead;
        }
    }

    public override Task<int> ReadAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //could be extended here with a proper async read
        var result = Read(buffer, offset, count);
        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _smSegmentsAvailable.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    public override bool CanRead => true;
    public override bool CanSeek => false;
    public override bool CanWrite => true;

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
        => throw new NotSupportedException();

    public override void SetLength(long value)
        => throw new NotSupportedException();

    public override void Flush() {}

    public override long Length => throw new NotSupportedException();

    public override long Position
    {
        get => throw new NotSupportedException();
        set => throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A late answer but there is a [Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=netcore-3.1) support in .NET Framework since version 2.0. Use [ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netcore-3.1) for thread safe operations.

I created the below implementation of a `Stream` which will `Read` and `ReadLines` when the bytes become available. Not the best implementation but it should do the job.

```
public class QueueStream : Stream
{
    protected readonly ConcurrentQueue<byte> Queue = new ConcurrentQueue<byte>();

    public Task? DownloadTask { get; set; }

    public override bool CanRead => true;

    public override bool CanSeek => false;

    public override bool CanWrite => true;

    public override long Length => Queue.Count;

    public override long Position
    {
        get => 0;
        set => throw new NotImplementedException($"{nameof(QueueStream)} is not seekable");
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        Queue.Clear();
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (buffer == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(buffer));
        }

        if (buffer.Length < count)
        {
            throw new Exception($"{nameof(buffer)} length is less that the specified {nameof(count)}");
        }

        var index = 0;
        var insertedCount = 0;
        while (Queue.TryDequeue(out var b) && insertedCount < count)
        {
            if (index >= offset)
            {
                buffer[insertedCount++] = b;
            }

            index++;
        }

        return insertedCount;
    }

    public string ReadLines(int numberOfLines = 1)
    {
        var currentLine = 0;
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        Func<bool> isFaulted = () => false;
        Func<bool> isCompleted = () => true;

        if (DownloadTask != null)
        {
            isFaulted = () => DownloadTask.IsFaulted;
            isCompleted = () => DownloadTask.IsCompleted;
        }

        while (!isFaulted() && !isCompleted() && currentLine < numberOfLines)
        {
            if (!Queue.TryDequeue(out var byteResult))
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (byteResult == '\r' || byteResult == '\n')
            {
                if (byteResult == '\r')
                {
                    byte peekResult = 0;
                    while (!isFaulted() && !isCompleted() && !Queue.TryPeek(out peekResult))
                    {
                    }

                    if (peekResult == '\n')
                    {
                        Queue.TryDequeue(out _);
                    }
                }

                stringBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                currentLine++;
                continue;
            }

            stringBuilder.Append((char)byteResult);
        }

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        var forEnd = offset + count;
        for (var index = offset; index < forEnd; index++)
        {
            Queue.Enqueue(buffer[index]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: note that `ConcurrentQueue<>.Clear()` isn't available in .NET Frameworks at all

Comment: there is a bug in `Read`, which may skip bytes, when reading: the loop condition should be reordered this way - `while (insertedCount < count && Queue.TryDequeue(out var b)) ...`