# How to deserialize JSON text on the fly in C#

Tags: c#, json, stream, .net-5, system.text.json

I am reading/receiving blocks of bytes from an async function which I buffer in a MemoryStream and then deserialize to a C# object.

```
    public async Task<Message> Read()
    {
        byte[] block = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;

        using var ms = new MemoryStream();
        while ((bytesRead = await GetBlock(block)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(block, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var result = await System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Message>(ms);
        return result;
    }
```

I would prefer a method that would not buffer the whole data and keep a potentially large byte array in memory. Like a Dummy-Stream that forwards each block of bytes to the Desirailize function as it is beeing received by the GetBlocks function.

```
    public async Task<Message> Read()
    {
        byte[] block = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;

        using var rs = new RedirectStream((rs) =>
        {
            while ((bytesRead = await GetBlock(block)) > 0)
            {
                rs.Write(block, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        });

        var result = await System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Message>(rs);
        return result;
    }
```

Does such a stream class exist or would I need to create my own (and if yes - where would I start?).

In addition to that, it would be interesting to know if the DeserializeAsync function would even be able to make good use of such a mechanism (meaning not reading the stream to the end before actually starting to deserialize it).

Comment: Do you receive multiple separate objects? or just one big object?

Comment: only one big object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does such a stream class exist

To my knowledge, there is nothing similar to your `RedirectStream` in the standard library, so you may have to implement it yourself, [like other folks already did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221136). A search for a NuGet package doesn't give pertinent results (like https://github.com/MarcusChr/BlockBasedMemoryStream where the `removeReadData` is misplaced and can't be used in your case).

> [Does] `DeserializeAsync` function would even be able to make good use of such a mechanism

**Actual** version of `JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync` use the `Stream.ReadAsync`  method as you can see from [the sources](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/b8b81a66738bb10ef0790023598396861d92b2c4/src/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonSerializer.Read.Stream.cs#L109). So yes, for now (it's unlikely there is a regression).

Comment: SlidingStream is a much better name than RedirectStream :) 
Too bad that is not part the standard library, but I should be able to create my own with inspiration from the linked post

Comment: It's your baby, you choose the name ;)