# Fast way to copy part of an array into a List?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, performance, memory

C#'s List<> has a set of CopyTo functions that will extract the contents of its internal array into another array using a fast memory block copy.

Is there a way to do this in reverse? It might look like...

```
var buffer = new List<byte>();
buffer.AddRange(afewbytes);
buffer.AddFromArray(myArray, startIndex, countBytesToCopy);
buffer.AddRange(afewmorebytes);
```

As my List is the List<byte> variety, I'd prefer to avoid a loop that copies byte by byte.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `List<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` constructor will use `ICollection<T>.CopyTo` if the collection implements `ICollection<T>`, which `byte[]` will do.

That's not going to help directly if you only want to extract *part* of the array, but you could create your own `ByteArraySegment` class implementing `ICollection<byte>` and implement the `CopyTo` operation using `Buffer.BlockCopy` or whatever:

```
public class ByteArraySegment : ICollection<byte>
{ 
    private readonly byte[] array;
    private readonly int start;
    private readonly int count;

    public ByteArraySegment(...)
    {
        // Obvious code
    }

    public void CopyTo(byte[] target, int index)
    { 
        Buffer.BlockCopy(array, start, target, index, count);
    }

    // Other ICollection<T> members
}
```

Then:

```
List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>(new ByteArraySegment(myArray, start, count));
```

(Or use `AddRange` which has the same optimization.)

Comment: Many thanks! I've edited my question to clarify I'm looking for an efficient Add rather than a constructor, but from the looks of the comments on David's answer, your class should work for AddRange too.

Comment: Are we really sure that we can trust this Jon Skeet chap?  ;)

Comment: You can never be sure with Jon Skeet... some say, he's not even real!

Answer (score 4):

To copy part of an array, wrap the array in an `ArraySegment`, specifying the index and count of the segment. Add the `ArraySegment` to the list with the list's `AddRange` method. `AddRange` will use `ArraySegment.CopyTo`, which uses `Array.Copy`, which is [fast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1389821/145173).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer !

Answer (score 3):

`List.AddRange(myArray)` should be pretty efficient.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): "If the new Count (the current Count plus the size of the collection) will be greater than Capacity, the capacity of the List is increased by automatically reallocating the internal array to accommodate the new elements, and the existing elements are copied to the new array before the new elements are added."

Comment: List<byte>.AddRange takes an IEnumerable<byte> as a parameter. Isn't that going to handle each byte one-by-one? (Instead of as a block)

Comment: Nope, it will interpret it as an ICollection and perform an Array.Copy which is as fast as memcpy (it probably uses memcpy under the hood).

Comment: @Asik, AddRange combined with the code in Jon's answer should do the trick then. Many thanks!