# Array.Copy between differently typed arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, memcpy

As you know, `Array.Copy` is faster than manually copying the contents of an array to another, because it does a straight memory copy from one location to another.

But let's say I have a `short[]` and a `char[]`. You can't do an `Array.Copy` between them because they're not of the same type, **but the elements in them are the same size,** i.e. `sizeof(short) == sizeof(char)`. How do I circumvent the type limitation to do a `memcpy` from the `short[]` to the `char[]`, without doing a for loop? I'm talking about something that would be the logical equivalent of `reinterpret_cast<>` in C++.

**TL;DR:** If two arrays have elements of the same size, can you manipulate that to copy elements between them faster? You could always have a for loop, but I'm looking for something more like a straight `memcpy` from one array to the other.

---

Also, I'd like to note one more time that **for loops will not be accepted.** I am well aware of them, but this is a performance question asking if there is a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Have you tried Buffer.BlockCopy?

Comment: May want to refer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3783189

Comment: @KellyEthridge && nawfal: Well, I guess you guys just answered my question...

Comment: If your question is answered, please either post an answer or ask the commenters who answered to post an answer, so that the question is actually shown **as having an answer**.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I thought when people saw that comment people would rush to answer my question. Hopefully this comment will bump it up so someone sees this and I can get an extra +2 rep. If not I'll answer it myself.

Comment: IMHO, you should worry less about the rep and more about the integrity of the site. Leaving present and unanswered a question for which you no longer seek an answer leads others to potentially waste time checking your question so that they can help, or makes it more difficult for others with a similar question to find the actual answer (since it's hidden in the comments instead of a well-marked answer). Note that if you answer the question and someone else finds it and up-votes it, you stand to gain more than the +2 you are considering at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Buffer.BlockCopy`. Unlike `Array.Copy`, it copies the underlying bytes of the array to the destination. So for example, a `short` is made up of 2 bytes. An empty `short[]` of 5 might look like this:

```
                 1 short (0x0000)
                        ˅˅˅˅
    0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
         ^^          ^^
    1 byte (0x00)  Byte #8 (byte index 7)
```

Meanwhile, let's say we have a `byte[]`, this time with 10 indices. It'll look something like this:

```
                             Last byte [9]
                                   ˅˅
        AF C0 24 19 05 67 F9 D7 24 B3
        ^^
    First byte [0]
```

Now, notice that these arrays are the exact same size: the `short[]` is 5 x 2 bytes, while the `byte[]` is 10 x 1. So if we ran a `Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, shorts, 0, bytes.Length)`, which essentially copies the bytes over from `bytes` to `shorts`, the shorts would become:

```
AFC0 2419 0567 F9D7 24B3
```

So yeah, that's essentially what Buffer.BlockCopy does- it copies the underlying bytes of the array.

---

Some tips:

- Use the array with smaller-sized elements for getting the count. For example, if I had used `shorts.Length` as the last parameter in the example above, I would have had to multiply it by `sizeof(short)` or it would only copy half the array.
- BlockCopy doesn't work with primitives.