# Selecting a range of items inside an array in C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I would like to select a range of items in an array of items.
For example I have an array of 1000 items, and i would like to "extract" items 100 to 200 and put them in another array.

Can you help me how this can be done?

Comment: Make sure to accept an answer if it helps you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array slices in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406485/array-slices-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 131, accepted):

In C# 8, range operators allow:

```
var dest = source[100..200];
```

(and a range of other options for open-ended, counted from the end, etc)

Before that, LINQ allows:

```
var dest = source.Skip(100).Take(100).ToArray();
```

or manually:

```
var dest = new MyType[100];
Array.Copy(source, 100, dest, 0, 100);
       // source,source-index,dest,dest-index,count
```

Comment: It also has to be a core app. dot net 4.8 doesn't like it even if it's C#9, missing System.Range and System.Index.

Comment: @MarcGravell It seems odd to me that array[1..10] creates a new array with a copy of the data (and appears to be syntactic shorthand for RuntimeHelpers.GetSubArray()); whereas span[1..10] gets a slice on that span (and is shorthand for .Slice()). I imagine this has come about due to legacy reasons, but to me it feels like it fails the "test of least astonishment".

Comment: I find C#'s syntax of excluding the last item in the range unintuitive using the `source[100..200]` syntax. Specifically, the OP asked items 100 to 200 to be extracted, which should include item 200, i.e. it is 101 items in total. @MarcGravell's solution excludes item 200.