# accessing a subarray in vb.net (or the equivalent)

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays

I read a an array of bytes from a file
I pass this to a class that then assigns various bytes from that array to various members of varying sizes.

Ideally i would like to do something like this

```
memberThatIsAUShort = bitconverter.ToUShort(tempArray.subArray(3,5))
memberThatIsAShort = bitconverter.ToShort(tempArray.subArray(6,8))
```

Instead of looping through the array, copying the bytes to new shorter array and passing them in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this as:

```
memberThatIsAUShort = BitConverter.ToUInt16(tempArray,3)
memberThatIsAShort = BitConverter.ToInt16(tempArray,6)
```

These methods are both static (hence `BitConverter` casing), and already provide a startIndex parameter.  Since BitConverter already knows the appropriate number of bytes for a short/ushort, you don't need to specify end indices.  For details, see [BitConverter.ToUInt16](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.touint16.aspx) and [BitConverter.ToInt16](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint16.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Although your syntax is wrong, I think I understand your intent and believe that something like this answer will suit you fine:

[Array Slices in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406485/array-slices-in-c)

Comment: This really somewhat answers the question, but doesn't solve the actual problem that the OP is trying to solve.  No array manipulation is required, just conversion.

Comment: I agree, leaving it for the sake of answering future slice questions. +1 to your answer.