# How can I assign a value to multiple array indices at once without looping?

Tags: c#, arrays

How can I set one value to several elements of the array in C#?

#### Example:

I have an array initialized as follows:

```
int[] array=new int[]{2,3,5,3,7,2,9}
```

and I want to set the values between the 2-nd and 5-th indices to 8.
How it can be done?

Comment: Just to clarify; do you want array elements 2 to 5 to get assigned, or element with *values* between 2 and 5?

Comment: I want the elements INDEXES 2 and 5 were set to 8 not the VALUES of 2 and 5.

Comment: Not looping when a loop is clearly the most efficient way to do what you want seems to me to be bad form. I smell bad code. We try to promote good code as a matter of course on SO. I contributed to the answer and gave you some ways to do bad code, but I don't have to like it. I'm just voicing this for the next person who thinks "oh yes, I'll avoid iterating explictly in my code" because I don't want to have to support that code later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you wanted to get cute, you could create another array that has the value repeated N times, and `Copy` that to the array:

```
int[] a = new int[]{2,3,5,3,7,2,9}
int[] replacement = new int[]{8, 8, 8, 8};
Array.Copy(replacement, 0, a, 1, 4);
```

There's no *explicit* loop there.  But you can bet that there's an implicit loop.

And, if you really wanted to get cute, you could use LINQ to create the `replacement` array.

Still, this is all academic.  As somebody else pointed out, there's no non-looping way to do what you're asking--just highly obfuscated ways that attempt to hide the fact that a loop is taking place.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of options in this post: [Array slices in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406485/array-slices-in-c)

There's no magic to set all the options to a value. You're going to have to iterate. But you could always do something like .Take(2) then loop to add 8 for three places, then .Skip(3).Take(rest) or something. Just depends how large the array is.

For large arrays this might help, but it's going to be a lot uglier code if you're only working with Ints or the like. I would just iterate.

Answer (score 1):

Just put it in a loop (assuming you want to set the second through fifth elements):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    array[i] = 8;
}
```

Comment: Linq is not magic; it will iterate over the array under the hood.

Comment: LINQ isn't magic? Are you going to tell me Santa isn't real too? :)

Comment: I know LINQ isn't magic. I  just tried to find out what I could implement with it avoiding redundancy in code :)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over it and set the appropiate values. There is no shortcut for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0;i<100;i++){
if(i=0)
{array[i]=2}
else{array[i]=(array[i-1]+3)}
}
```

Comment: No, it looks very ugly, I still don't understand what it does :(

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd give an alternate approach which is pretty cool.

```
int[] array = new int[] { 2,3,5,3,7,2,9 };
var segment = new ArraySegment<int>( array, 2, 5 );
for (int i = segment.Offset; i <= segment.Count; i++)
{
    segment.Array[i] = 8;
}
```

Comment: ArraySegment? I've never heard about it before. Anyway it's also very cute way. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I choose recursion.

```
int[] array = new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 3, 7, 2, 9 };
public void caller()
{
    Array8(2, 5);
}

public void Array8 (int start, int end)
{
    if (start <= end)
        Array8(start, --end);
    array[end] = 8;
}
```

Comment: It's nice for small arrays but what would you do with big arrays? It will fill your stack up ;)