# Use the data in a c# byte array

Tags: c#, struct, arrays

I have an image, including image header, stored in a c# byte array (byte []).

The header is at the beginning of the byte array.
If I put the header in a struct (as I did in c++) it looks like this:

```
typedef struct RS_IMAGE_HEADER
{
   long HeaderVersion;
   long Width;
   long Height;
   long NumberOfBands;
   long ColorDepth;
   long ImageType;
   long OriginalImageWidth;
   long OriginalImageHeight;
   long OffsetX;
   long OffsetY;
   long RESERVED[54];
   long Comment[64];

} RS_IMAGE_HEADER;
```

How can I do it in c#, how can I get and use all the data in the image header (that stored in the beginning of the byte array)?

Thanks

Comment: Do you just want the info? or do you **specifically** want to load it into the struct? (both are possible). The first is easier, of course - `BitConverter.ToInt64(data, 0)` will probably do it if the endianness is correct... or you could "shift" and "or".

Comment: If you want to read directly into the struct, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871/reading-a-c-c-data-structure-in-c-sharp-from-a-byte-array

Comment: what's wrong with `BitMap` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Structs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) are perfectly fine in C#, so there should be no issue with the struct pretty much exactly as you've written it, though you might need to add permission modifiers such as `public`.  To convert byte arrays to other primitives, there are a very helpful class of methods that include [ToInt64()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384066%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that will help you convert an array of bytes to another built in type (in this case `long`).  To get the specific sequences of array bytes you'll need, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406485/array-slices-in-c-sharp) on various techniques for doing array slices in C#.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create an analog data structure in c#, I won't go into that here as it is almost the same. An example to read out individual the bytes from the array is below.

```
int headerVersionOffset = ... // defined in spec
byte[] headerVersionBuffer = new byte[sizeof(long)];
Buffer.BlockCopy(imageBytes, headerVersionOffset, headerVersionBuffer, 0, sizeof(long));
//Convert bytes to long, etc.
long headerVersion = BitConverter.ToInt64(headerVersionBuffer, 0);
```

You would want to adapt this to your data structure and usage, you could also accomplish this using a stream or other custom data structures to automatically handle the data for you.