# How to access second Dimension of Array

Tags: c#, arrays

Following situation:
I have a Array which got 2 dimension. No i want to access the second dimension. How can i achieve this goal?

Here my code to clarify my problem:

```
private static int[,] _Spielfeld = new int[_Hoehe, _Breite];

    private static bool IstGewonnen(int spieler)
    {
        bool istGewonnen = false;

        for (int zaehler = 0; zaehler < _Spielfeld.GetLength(0); zaehler++)
        {
            //Here i cant understand why compiler doesnt allow
            //Want to give the second dimension on the Method
            istGewonnen = ZeileSpalteAufGewinnPruefen(_Spielfeld[zaehler] ,spieler);
        }

        return istGewonnen;
    }

//This method want to become an Array
private static bool ZeileSpalteAufGewinnPruefen(int[] zeileSpalte, int spieler)
{ 
  //Some further code
}
```

The compiler is saying: "Argument from type int[,] is not assignable to argument of type int[]. In Java it is working as i expected. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aside from the syntax, why would "spieler" be a value for "Breite" of the array?

Comment: have you tried ARRAY[1D][2D] ?

Comment: You can't access just a row or column of a 2D array. You need to slice it out int it's own 1D array. Or use jagged array instead of rectangular array.

Comment: Please consult the documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx 
You access an array's value like _Spielfeld[0,0]...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# allows two different offers [two flavors of multidimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-is-differences-between-multidimensional-array-and-array-of-arrays-in-c) which, although they look quite similar, handle quite differently in practice.

What you have there is a true [multidimensional array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx), from which you cannot automatically extract a slice. That would be possible (as in Java) if you had a [jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) instead.

If the choice of having a multidimensional array is deliberate and mandatory then you will have to extract slices manually; for example see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/406485/50079).

If the choice between jagged and multidimensional is open then you can also consider switching to a jagged array and getting the option of slicing for free.

Answer (score 3):

Define your array as a jagged array (array of arrays):

```
private static int[][] _Spielfeld = new int[10][];
```

Then loop through the first dimension and initialize.

```
for (int i = 0; i < _Spielfeld.Length; i++)
{
    _Spielfeld[i] = new int[20];
}
```

Then the rest of your code will compile OK.