# extract some parts of a string array in c#

Tags: c#

I have a string array with 31 strings, now I have to extract string from 3rd position to 27th position and pass that part as an string array to another function. how do I accomplish this in c#?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943635/c-sharp-arrays-getting-a-sub-array-from-an-existing-array or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406485/array-slices-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.Copy(Array, Int32, Array, Int32, Int32)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ;

> Copies a range of elements from an Array starting at the specified
>   source index and pastes them to another Array starting at the
>   specified destination index.

```
Array.Copy(source, 2, destination, 0, 25);
```

But this create a new array. You can use LINQ istead with [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods like;

```
var destination = source.Skip(2).Take(25).ToArray();
```

I assume you want *27th* position also, that's why I used `25` as a length (or count) in both example. If you don't want to get *27th* position, you need to change `25` to `24` in both case.

Answer (score 1):

If you have linq you can do something like:

```
var finalResult = foo(myStrings.Skip(2).Take(25).ToArray())
```

Comment: This is not OP wants. This takes 27 elements after third element. OP wants to get 3rd position to 27th position.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
  var arr2 = arr1.Select( x => x.substring(3,27));
```

Comment: Erm, no. It's not *one* string, but an array of strings.

Comment: List<string> arr1 = new List<string> { "test1", "test2", "test3" }, then the above will work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple if you use LINQ.

```
var arrayToPassToMethod = array.Skip(2).Take(24).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string[][] result = a.Skip(2).Take(24).ToArray<string[]>();
```