# Replace from start index on array C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have char [] like `{'Q','W','E','a','b','c','A','B','C'}`

i want to put this char [] start from index 3 `{'1',2','3'}`

the result need to be  `{'Q','W','E','1',2','3''A','B','C'}`
how can i do that please?

thanks

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Use a `for` loop.

Comment: this is not a `char[]`, but a `string[]`. the concept is called splicing, there are many good posts, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/406485/1132334)

Comment: Not to be nit-picky but your array examples are for strings not chars

Answer (score 3):

It could be done using Linq as follows.

```
string[] Op1 = {"a","f","h","x","k","w","7"};
string[] Op2 = {"1",2","3"};
int StartIndex = 3;
string[] Result = Op1.Take(StartIndex).Concat(Op2).ToArray();
```

Comment: sorry... i edit the post
i need the rest of char after the concat