# Can't slice an array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, slice

So I am looking at the following example (http://zetcode.com/lang/csharp/arrays/), titled "c# array slices". When I copy and paste the following example in Microsoft Visual Studio:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace s_Sandbox
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
                array[1..2];
            }
        }
    }
```

There is a red underline under `[1..2]` and I get a `Syntax error, "," expected` ... why is this? What am I missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406485/array-slices-in-c-sharp/55498674#55498674

Comment: this is supported starting with c# 8

Comment: @Steve that does not answer why I am getting the error; rather an alternate solution.

Comment: @Homungus I have viewed the property settings for my solution, I am using .NET Framework 4.5.2... that shouldn't be an issue though?

Comment: look here how to use c# 8.0 with asp.net project: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56651472/does-c-sharp-8-support-the-net-framework

Comment: Even if you enable C# 8, you still can't use the `range` operator when building for the .Net Framework 4.x. [unless you take some additional steps](https://www.meziantou.net/how-to-use-csharp-8-indices-and-ranges-in-dotnet-standard-2-0-and-dotn.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the `range operator` [n..m] is available for version C# 8.0 or greater

This might be useful too

```
Target framework    version C# language version default
.NET Core   3.x C# 8.0
.NET Core   2.x C# 7.3
.NET Standard   2.1 C# 8.0
.NET Standard   2.0 C# 7.3
.NET Standard   1.x C# 7.3
.NET Framework  all C# 7.3
```

If upgrading is not an option you can use:

```
      int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
      var t = array.Take(2);
```