# Error: Predefined type 'System.Range' is not defined or imported

Tags: c#, .net, range, slice

Earlier I was getting the error:

`Feature 'range operator' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 8.0 or greater.`

When I upgraded the project below error still remains:

`Predefined type 'System.Range' is not defined or imported`

Basically trying to test how can we retrieve a fragment of an array or string:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestRange
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var story = "Testing C# 8";
            Console.WriteLine(story[^6..^0]); // (last 6 chars)
        }
    }
}
```

Articles that I referred to but didn't help:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.range?view=netcore-3.1
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes

https://www.infoworld.com/article/3532284/how-to-use-indices-and-ranges-in-csharp-80.html

https://www.codejourney.net/2019/02/csharp-8-slicing-indexes-ranges/

One related question: [Array slices in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406485/array-slices-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Are you able to provide a screenshot of your Project Properties.

Comment: [screenshot1](https://i.imgur.com/sq62gJW.png)

Comment: [screenshot2](https://i.imgur.com/dRtzrZp.png)

Comment: C# 8 is only supported in .Net Core 3 and above.

Comment: You will either need to migrate your project over to .Net Core 3.1, or not use `System.Range`

Comment: @Hayden that's not true.. you can specify language specification at the project level. in a .NetFramework project (old or new SDK) you add `<LangVersion>8.0<\LangVersion>`.   The issue you'll face is not designating your project language to be 8.0 (as opposed to the default it uses through target file associated to the project and IDE) it is that certain assemblies are imported by specific TFMs.

Comment: @BrettCaswell Although correct, System.Range is NOT implemented in .Net Framework 4.7.2 (which he is currently using). What I've said above still holds true for what he wants to achieve.

Comment: System.Range and System.Index won't be imported for this project targeting .Netframework even if you did add LangVersion to your project file.  However, handling that issue is a matter of 'implementing'  the specification; and so, a means of implmenting it (and mitigate the imported issue) is by downloading\including IndexRange (3rd party) nuget package for netstandard2.0 and .NetFramework c#8.

Answer (score 1):

As a solution for .NET Framework 461 or smth like there, you can use this NuGet package in your csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Contrib.Bcl.Ranges" Version="1.0.0"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: seems to work though I get warning: "CS1685: The predefined type 'RuntimeHelpers' is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'Contrib.Bcl.Ranges, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'"

Comment: Oh yeah I also had the same warning